# Is it possible to boot Ubuntu using the Windows bootloader?

Tags: boot, uefi

As noted by many people, Windows 8's UEFI requirements <s>might</s> <s>will</s> won't get in the way of installing Linux (or whatever), as the replacement bootloader will also need to be signed *somehow.* <s>Some systems</s> All systems will let you disable the signature requirement, but the feature might be hidden to disable or you might not be willing to give up on the benefits of a secure bootloader.

Is it necessary to replace the bootloader in the first place? To keep ourselves to software that's gone golden, how can I install Ubuntu 11.04 using Windows 7's own bootloader?

Answer (score 35):

Assuming that Windows is already installed, install Ubuntu on another partition.  Make sure that you install Grub2 on the Ubuntu partition - don't install it on the MBR since this will overwrite the Windows boot-loader.

Boot into Windows and install [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1)

Add Entry and choose Grub2 i.e.

[image]

Then write back the modified Windows Boot-loader i.e.

[image]

Reboot - you will now have two options:

[image]

Boot into Ubuntu and change the Grub Timeout value i.e.

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

change "GRUB_TIMEOUT=10" to "GRUB_TIMEOUT=0" and save.

Finally:

```
sudo update-grub
```

[source](http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Ubuntu)

Comment: On newer EasyBCD, you don't need to perform the Write MBR step because it restores the default one, with windows only. You only have to add the Grub 2 menu entry, and save it.

Comment: EasyBCD, as far as I've seen, does not work with uefi bootloaders. It will only work with mbr.

Comment: Does this work if ubuntu and windows are installed i different hdd instead of same hdd different partitions? Also does it have to be grub2 or grub is fine too?

Comment: `Make sure that you install Grub2 on the Ubuntu partition - don't install it on the MBR` – does that mean (on the Ubuntu installer "something else" → "Device for boot loader installation" to use `/dev/sda` instead of `/dev/sda1` (windows), or should I really go for Linux (`/boot`, due to encryption) partition (`/dev/sda4` in my case)?

Answer (score 9):

I've been through it. Here's the way I solved it.

You need to restore MBR, so it boots into Windows again, not Linux, THEN add Linux.

1. Boot from Windows installation disk;
2. Choose Repair/Startup repair; Windows will restore MBR;
3. When done, reboot into Windows;
4. Open EasyBCD, and add Linux;
5. On reboot, you will see the good old black screen with Windows bootloader and two entries: Windows and Linux;
6. Voila.

Comment: I read "MBR" in this answer, but the title of the question said "UEFI". And UEFI usually means EFI partition for booting, not MBR. right?

Answer (score 3):

I've found this very usefull but found an easier way to fix this.
When you have access to your windows installation and have EasyBCD installed. You can just repair you MBR from within the tool.(done with EasyBCD 2.2.0.182)

1. Open EasyBCD and click on "BCD Deployement"
2. In the section "MBR Configuration Options" ensure that "Install the Windows Vista/7 bootloader to the MBR" is selected and click the "Write MBR" button
3. Reboot and enjoy the magic of Windows Bootloader

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

You could go to shell in boot menu and type:

```
chroot / 
mount /dev/sda /grub/boot
mount /dev/sda2 /win
install grub boot loader again on sda
```

this could might work.

Comment: What does `chroot /` do? Is that an actual command, `install grub boot loader again on sda` ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the UEFI or GPT partition to MBR, which can be done by reinstalling Windows, using Partition Master by EaseUS (https://appuals.com/convert-uefi-to-legacy-bios-on-windows-7-8-and-10/, free), AOMEI Partition Assistant (https://www.diskpart.com/gpt-mbr/convert-gpt-to-mbr-without-data-loss-using-command-prompt.html), or other tools. Then you can use easyBCD to add Ubuntu or other OSs to the windows boot menu.

Comment: Why would you need to reinstall Windows to do this? Couldn't you just boot a Live USB and use Fdisk/similar? This seems completely unnecessary.

Comment: Perhaps we can simply use a live USB, I'm not sure. From what I was reading, you need to use one of the commercial tools or reinstall.