# How to make Windows boot first?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, dual-boot, windows-7, bootloader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)

I want to know how to make Windows the default boot OS in Ubuntu 11.10, how to make Windows boot first on GRUB2, specifically for Windows 7, which is my current version.

I know that are some tutorials about this, but it seems that I made a mistake, so I'm asking. Luckily nothing serious happened.  I didn't lose my data.

The difference between my question and the tutorials is that the tutorials are from older version.

Sorry for any disturbs and redundancy of the question.

I'll love it better for a GUI app that making easy the boot.

P.S: I forgot to say the version of my OS's

I am running

1. Windows 7 Home Premium X64 bit
2. Ubuntu 11.10 X64 bit

I hope this will make understand better because I now saw it a tutorial that for 64 bit versions Startup-Manager doesn't work.