# How to remove Ubuntu from dual boot system with Windows?

Tags: partitioning, dual-boot, windows-7, uninstall

I wish to remove Ubuntu and I'm not quite sure how. I know it has something to do with partitions. I have 3 partitions. 1. OS [683 GB]  2. Recovery [14 GB] 3. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (E:)

I know it says Ubuntu but when I installed Ubuntu I think I put 14 gigabytes for it so I think its the recovery one but I'm not sure. I could have sworn I put more than 700 megabytes for it.

I have googled this and I can't seem to find an answer. Any help would be nice.

[image]

Comment: Um, E: drive is you CD drive, Hit the eject button on the CD drive and that will be gone.

Comment: yes you are rite @mateo_salta .. i think he's using live Ubuntu cd & thinking that its installed on system

Comment: before following any answer here you need to know if you installed Ubuntu via Wubi, the answers are different and using the wrong one could frag your system

Comment: For readers who find this page by searching *but do not have a Wubi installation*, [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on) may help.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any ext2 ext 3 or ext4 filesystems which would be a regular Ubuntu install, this leads me to wonder-did you install Ubuntu using Wubi???

If so you  can just remove it with your Windows add and Remove Programs window, It should be listed as "Ubuntu"  as far as Windows is concerned it's just another program and can be removed

Also as the comment to your question said and I also belive, the 12.04LTS that is showing is an Ubuntu install CD.

Answer (score 3):

I have your answer.

1. Boot to a live CD with Ubuntu
2. Go to a live session
3. Download and install [os-uninstaller](https://launchpad.net/os-uninstaller) with the 3 DEBs on the website.
4. Start the software and select what operating system you want to uninstall.
   [image: os-uninstaller-fr]
5. Then click on "Validate" and the soft will do the rest.
6. When all is over, reboot your computer, and that's it, only windows is on your computer!

Comment: Has anyone tried this? Looks too easy...

Comment: I did for my dual-boot Windows 7/Ubuntu. And after it removed my ubuntu system, I just had to run gparted to ask him to give to Windows, all free space. And that's all. If you want a picture of my hard drive as a proof, I can send it to you in PM.

Comment: FYI I just rendered my laptop unbootable with that tool. Had to use a Windows DVD to fix the MBR.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an UEFI boot PC, you'll encounter a problem with GRUB, because GRUB is partially installed on EFI partition and has the priority while booting.
What I did is that after uninstalling Ubuntu ,you can do that the mentioned way, or by simply booting into Ubuntu live CD or USB stick and formatting Linux partitions with GParted, I formatted the EFI partition as well, and then did Windows boot recovery from Windows installation disk.

I have to mention i read dozens of advice and tutorials and lost bunch of time with methods that don't work. In the end I did the only thing that seemed logical to me be4 reinstalling windows and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot into Windows partition, and use the free, non-commercial version of [EasyBCD](https://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to reinstall the Windows bootloader.
2. Reboot and check that you're not using grub anymore.
3. Delete the Ubuntu partition and extend the Windows partition using the Windows Disk Management tool. Right-click the volume next to the empty space, and select *Extend Volume* to increase the size of the partition.

   [image: Disk Management]