# Uninstall ubuntu 12.04 from my win7

Tags: dual-boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove Ubuntu from dual boot system with Windows 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152812/how-to-remove-ubuntu-from-dual-boot-system-with-windows-7)

Is it safe to uninstall Ubuntu from my Windows 7 computer? My default OS is now Ubuntu and can't change it to Windows 7.

I am just bored of Ubuntu which lowers my battery life quicker than Windows.

Comment: Do you have an nvidia optimus enabled / hybrid graphics laptop? that could cause faster batter life. Otherwise ubuntu uses less battery than windows. If so let us know, we can help

Answer (score 4):

What I used to do when I wanted to uninstall Ubuntu from my dual-boot desktop was to delete the Linux partitions via disk management and then use a Windows 7 CD to restore MBR. You can find detailed step-by-step [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-safely-uninstall-ubuntu-in-windows-dual-boot-environment/).

Comment: i cant boot my windows 7 plz help me in that...actually i selected Ubuntu as my default os...and in ubuntu there is no option for Select windows 7 as defualt

Answer (score 0):

There is no way ubuntu lowers your battery faster than Windows. . .
Full charge it leave it as it is, and count the time of windows and ubuntu to make the battery go 50%... Ubuntu ofc wins ;)

P.s use gparted live cd to unistall ubuntu ;)