# I need help on how to uninstall ubuntu I might have install it as uefi while my windows 10 32 bit was in legacy bios

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uninstall

I need some serious help plzzz messed up my father's computer
I alredy had windows 10 32 bit legacy bios installed on the laptop.I installed ubuntu 22.04( for some reason It made an efi partition) I alredy have  full four partion MBR )
during installation I chose the option install windows along side windows 10. which could have been a mistake instead I should have selected the option something else. Before intall I freed some space I removed my local disk E partion of 189 gb to give that to ubuntu. after install and restarted the system and it showed invalid partion table I ignored it and hit enter showed me the grub screen.

Grub screen showed windows 10 and ubuntu I select windows 10 to check my files are ok, Inaddition to this I am not  keeping a back up of them as I do not have a external hard drive to do soo I am ubale to shutdown my computer this is may be due to  efi partion
now I want to uninstall the ubuntu cause it is not my computer I must not had interfered with my father computer.
I already tried deleting volume form windows  of  ubuntu, and I also deleted the efi partition from windows files manager format that efi partion ( that was not a good idea).but it showed the grub screen rescue , I was stuck on the BLACK SCREEN OF DEATH any how I reinstalled ubuntu the same way to get the grub back on working, thank god it work I was able to boot into windows and all the files were safe and now I am here I need desprate help to restore my  father's computer as it was cause I do not want to spend my night in the grave yard.

I am attaching all of the screen shot of the disk management situation [disk management pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arjLo.png)
and I am also attaching my system info
[system info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqAMh.png)
and I am also planning to follow this tutorial
can this work
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Rq4zovHiWk&ab_channel=EasyTechs

Comment: Microsoft required Windows to be installed in UEFI boot mode since 2012. Since system is UEFI, why is Windows 10 in BIOS mode? And hardware is 64 bit, so it should have been 64 bit Windows. You must have backups before doing anything as any mistake will just make things worse. If old BIOS install, you have to use Windows repair flash drive to reinstall Windows BIOS boot loader to MBR. If UEFI, you just choose to boot Windows from UEFI boot menu. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156795/windows-hard-disk-read-only-now-windows-is-removed?noredirect=1#comment1925839_1156795

Comment: Ensure your system booting is controlled by windows, or you'll risk your machine not booting again.  Usually the last installed OS will control the boot process; which means if Ubuntu was last installed; it'll control boot. Windows has commands to take ownership of boot back; use them.  After that's confirmed good, you can use windows to just remove whatever isn't required; as an OS is **not** installed; just written over.

Comment: @guiverc after some looking around I was able to find that there is an error invalid disk partition table due to 2 active partion as in pic shown of my disk info in my question how I can remove this partition as I already did with windows tool it break the whole computer if I delete the volume and partition  E  on which ubuntu is installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu from dual boot system with Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152812/how-to-remove-ubuntu-from-dual-boot-system-with-windows)