# Remove Ubuntu partition

Tags: dual-boot

I have dual booted my laptop with windows 7 and ubuntu 13.04. Now i want to remove my ubuntu partition. Is there any way to remove ubuntu partition without casing any harm to my  windows 7? I have tried to delete the ubuntu partition from my windows 7 but its not working. please suggest me the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good link on how to do this at [How to uninstall Ubuntu 11.10 in netbook](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83403/how-to-uninstall-ubuntu-11-10-in-netbook).  It is a little dated, but the procedure will be the same.