# Can Grub2 menu be hidden a la Windows?

Tags: grub2

Is there a way to hide the Grub2 menu so that it does not show by default and boots off the pre-selected OS immediately unless another key, like F8 in Windows, is pressed after BIOS to intercept the boot?

Comment: Answered in: _How to set Windows bootloader as default bootloader?_ http://askubuntu.com/questions/66070/how-to-set-windows-bootloader-as-default-bootloader

Answer (score 2):

Run `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub` Set GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT to the number of seconds you want to have to press shift before it starts booting and take the hash `#` mark out of in front of it. Save the file and the changes will be applied next time you boot.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this. I did not think setting timeout to zero will totally prevent the Grub menu from showing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you can.The easy way is the following:
Install startupmanager package by opening a  terminal window and typing
  `sudo apt-get install startupmanager`
Then run startupmanager and set timeout in seconds to 0 .Press the close button and once the "performing post-configuration tasks" window dissappears you are done !

```
`
```