# Uninstalling Ubuntu partition

Tags: uninstall

I want to uninstall Ubuntu that I have partitioned on my hard drive.

I want it uninstalled so that I can install the new version for Windows that allows for **dual booting** (alongside Windows). How do I get to the area where I can access Ubuntu that was partitioned?

I want to get to in so I can uninstall it before I install Ubuntu for Windows.

I tried creating an ISO image of Ubuntu on my USB drive, but I couldn't access the Welcome page of the program so I could get to the Allocate drive space portion, but it never showed up. Is that the way to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are planning to use WUBI from within Windows.

It's not necessary to uninstall Ubuntu from that partition. You can simply stop using it. It causes no difficulty to have several Ubuntu versions on one disk. In fact I do that all of the time. You should probably, simply, install WUBI and use that by booting into Windows at your current prompt.

You might want to make windows your default boot entry for your convenience. See [How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader/52990#52990) I understand that [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/106497/63886) is a way to make your system boot into Windows the way it originally did.

Comment: Hey, Thanks John! that's great to know that I can do that. Sorry I took so long responding, but I really appreciate that info. And, yes I do plan on installing WUBI from within Windows. Hopefully, it'll install and boot up with no hickups like I encountered the two times prior. Oh, and thanks for the extra tip on setting Windows to boot as the default loader, too. That's just what I want to do. Thanks again, John!