# Dual-boot bootrec /fixboot issues while uninstalling Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, windows-7

Good Day,

I want to give Ubuntu more HDD space so I tried to create a new partition then merge it with my Ubuntu's. Windows is unable to create more that 5 partitions I decided to uninstall then re-install Ubuntu.

I used a recovery disk to uninstall Ubuntu. I went into the command prompt and ran "bootrec /fixboot" the following message appeared "The volume does not contain a recognized file system. Please make sure that all the required file system drivers are loaded and that the volume is not corrupted."
"Bootrec /fixmbr" ran without any problems.

When I turned on the computer it booted into Windows 7

Question - Do I still need to run "bootrec /fixboot" or can I delete the Ubuntu Partition and run Windows 7 without any problems?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uninstalling Ubuntu from dual boot / changing bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106481/uninstalling-ubuntu-from-dual-boot-changing-bootloader) and [How to properly uninstall Ubuntu from dual boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336520/)

Answer (score 0):

**bootrec /fixboot** only fixes files (more precisely **bootmgr**) on the Windows partition. It should work without **/fixboot**.

More important is the fixed mbr. But if your Windows boots with the normal Windows boot loader (not grub), everything is fine.

Comment: Fingers crossed I'm ganna delete the partition and re install now :)

Comment: @GeorgeKingston Please **accept** this answer if it solved your problem.