# How to properly uninstall Ubuntu from dual boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uninstall

Is there any other way than this [Uninstalling Ubuntu from dual boot / Change bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106481/uninstalling-ubuntu-from-dual-boot-change-bootloader) ?

Don't have a windows 7 disk and my laptop won't go to recovery mode since the keys are broke on the laptop.

Is there any way to uninstall it without seeing

**No such partition**

**GRUB Rescue:**

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this [question and it's answers](http://askubuntu.com/q/133533/12218)

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [EasyBcd](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) in Windows First.
2. Go to BCD deployement tab as shown in below screenshot

   [image]
3. Click on write MBR slecting your version of Windows
4. Now from partition manager you can delete the partition with Ubuntu