# Uninstall Ubuntu from dual boot (separate drives) with Windows 10, fix Windows boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, grub-efi

I currently have a desktop computer with both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on it. Windows 10 is on drive C: and Ubuntu is installed on a 100 GB partition on drive D:

I'm not happy with Ubuntu 16.04 on my desktop and have instead fully installed it on my laptop. So I am now looking at uninstalling it off the desktop computer.

However I am having issues doing this as I can't delete the Ubuntu GRUB boot and replace it with my the proper Windows one. I have tried repairing the Windows boot (through the bootrec `/fixboot` command and bootrec `/fixMbr`) but it doesn't seem to work and I feel it may be because Ubuntu is on a different drive so therefore so is GRUB.

Can anyone help or suggest how this can be fixed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uninstalling Ubuntu from dual boot / changing bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106481/uninstalling-ubuntu-from-dual-boot-changing-bootloader) and [How to properly uninstall Ubuntu from dual boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336520/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope that you didn't deleted ubuntu yet. You need first to open `gparted` (`sudo apt-get install gparted`) , go to your hard disk with windows and ubuntu , and delete `boot` flag from ubuntu partition and set it to windows. Now it will boot directly in windows. Now in Windows , you need to delete the ext4 partition (with ubuntu). For partition on windows see this tool : http://www.partition-tool.com/