# How to uninstall Ubuntu from Legacy mode?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows 10 on my Lenovo laptop, but have run into some problems :)

Specifically, my problems seem to come from choosing UEFI or Legacy as the Bootmode in the BIOS.

Here is what I have found so far:

Windows 10 needs to boot using UEFI and doesn't work in the Legacy mode while Ubuntu needs to boot using Legacy mode.

So how I uninstall ubuntu from my Legacy mode?

Currently both Windows and Ubuntu are installed on my laptop and disk partitioning type is GPT.

Comment: can you show the partitions of your disk by opening GParted in your Ubuntu? At present you have only Ubuntu installed in your system? What is the disk Partitioning type? MBR or GPT?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uninstalling Ubuntu from dual boot / changing bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106481/uninstalling-ubuntu-from-dual-boot-changing-bootloader) and [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You are operating under a misconception. Ubuntu does not need to boot in Legacy mode. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031993/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-windows-10 might be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

What you say is wrong, windows 10 can also start in to legacy mode (it depend on the way you install it) I'm sure on this because I had to convert windows 10 mbr partition to GPT to move the boot in UEFI and Ubuntu also support UEFI and legacy boot.

Anyway you could do an installation to run a OS in to legacy at boot and another to UEFI only by the following condition:

- Installation reside in different disk (so you can have one with MBR and other with GPT)
- your BIOS support feature to boot legacy & UEFI