# Uninstall Ubuntu from dual boot with Windows in different drives

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall

I have both Windows and Ubuntu on my machine with dual boot. Windows is on the SSD, and Ubuntu is on a normal hard drive. I've tried the most common solution online, which is booting from a Windows repair USB stick and typing `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`. But that doesn't work. I've read somewhere that that only works for adjacent Windows and Linux partitions. So, how should I uninstall Ubuntu without any traces?

Answer (score 1):

1. set your ssd as the first boot option in the bios/uefi
2. if it doesent automatically boot to windows use the windows repair usb stick to restore the windows boot loader. if you have an mbr installation:

```
bootrec /FixMbr
bootrec /FixBoot
bootrec /ScanOs
bootrec /RebuildBcd
```

[for uefi use this guide](https://www.dell.com/support/article/hu/hu/hudhs1/sln300987/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-on-a-gpt-hdd-for-windows-7-8-8-1-and-10-on-your-dell-pc?lang=en)
if you are not sure try mbr first and if it fails try uefi method.

3. delete tour linux partition using windows disk management(right click on your start menu and select disk management)

   (4.) OPTIONAL for efi installation only mount the efi partition [as mentioned here](https://superuser.com/questions/662823/how-do-i-mount-the-efi-partition-on-windows-8-1-so-that-it-is-readable-and-write) and delete the ubuntu folder.

Comment: I already automatically boot to Windows as I have it as my first choice on the BIOS. So is it as simple as just deleting the Linux partition?

Comment: yes,  it as simple as just deleting the Linux partition.

Comment: I deleted the Linux partition, but there's a 512 MB EFI part in the way of me expanding my partition. I'm pretty sure it's just Dell junk that was installed when I installed Linux.

Comment: Also I tried formatting the Linux partition I deleted and it gives an error message.

Comment: The error is "not enough space on disk(s) to complete this operation".

Comment: An Efi partition isnt dell junk, its a boot partition for uefi systems. Can you make a screenshot of your partitions so I can better understand your situation?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/oIvz5gt

Comment: Since you have another efi partition on the C drive this was most likely created by linux and unnecessary now. You can delete it. In case the system has any problems to boot after, you can use the windows installer to fix any boot problems.

Comment: Do you mean the D drive? There's only one EFI partition in the C drive and it's for Windows. Also I can't delete the partition at all, even using diskpart.