# How do I hide the GRUB menu showing up at the beginning of boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I stopped dual booting and I don't want to have to choose the OS any more. I want to boot into Ubuntu 12.04 directly without seeing the GRUB menu.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: If you stopped dual booting, probably you have stopped using the other OS. Why cant you remove the other OS so that ubuntu can boot normally.

Comment: Duplicate of (either) http://askubuntu.com/questions/124074/dual-boot-default-question-w7-ubuntu or http://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader

Comment: if any of these answers "answered" your question please accept one of them :)

Comment: @david6: I don't see how either of those are duplicates of this question. I think this is about hiding the grub menu during the timeout.

Comment: Sorry, the second link was supposed to be: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66070/how-to-set-windows-bootloader-as-default-bootloader This includes how to: ***Hide the Grub2 menu, and use the default menu option***

Comment: It seems like there's a bug in 30_os-prober script that overrides the value of timeout and timeout_style variable. Has anybody reported it???

Comment: Aside from all the recipes you'll find, sometimes you need to get down to brass tacks. It is far from the first thing a search engine returns when searching for this kind of thing, so here's the documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Simple-configuration.html

Comment: For a solution involving the use of the software Boot Repair, see: <https://askubuntu.com/a/1119833/818816>

Answer (score 45):

#### You can just change grub settings.

**type in terminal**

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

[image: you need to change this]

Change `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false` to

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

Save the file and exit

Type `sudo update-grub`

If you don't get the result you want, see [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/647250).

Comment: it is currently changed to True but I still see the grub menu...

Comment: Im on 12.04 and i tried this but it already said "true" and it still shows up. The only other OS's I have are the failsafe and Memtest - that's it. I've already deleted my Windows Partition and updated grub and the menu still shows.

Comment: @AlexPoulos look at this [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/647250)

Comment: Worked for me by changing the timeout to 0 and then make it quiet. Thanks

Comment: Please note that this answer was written in 2012 and does not apply to newer Ubuntu versions unfortunately.

Answer (score 38):

I solved this problem by disabling the OS Prober. I did that because in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` in the part generated by the template `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`, there was an override of "timeout" to 10 and "style" to menu.

Edit `/etc/default/grub` and add this line:

```
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

Hope you find this useful!

BTW, my full /etc/default/grub is:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR= [...]
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
```

Happy coding

Comment: that worked for me, but it made dissapear al the other boot options but the default one...

Comment: @opensas If the selection menu isn't displayed, how do you even know what boot options "appear" on it? If you want to disable the menu, why would you want non-default boot options?

Comment: if you leave out the 'GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden' part, then the countdown is visible, but nothing else, unless you interrupt it. That allows you to get to the menu and change boot settings, even while making it much less obvious.

Comment: If one wants to be able see the boot menu after holding Shift key, GRUB_TIMEOUT must be set to **greater then zero** (say, GRUB_TIMEOUT=5). Otherwise, other boot options (say, Windows) can not be activated if needed.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0` is the **only** change to `/etc/default/grub` that eliminates the 30 second timeout (and the GRUB bootloader menu altogether), which seems to be a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1814403/comments/4 . Also, `sudo update-grub` must be executed for the edits to take effect, which is not mentioned in the Answer. Note that setting this value to `0` is not advised (see above-cited link) unless the machine is a development VM or similar.

Comment: You don't need to disable the OS Prober. See https://askubuntu.com/a/1197788/585408

Answer (score 12):

I tried all those tips they didnt work, ended up reducing the timeout time to zero as follows:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: run `sudo update-grub` after changing the values

Comment: Same for me. I ran "update-grub" - didn't work.

Comment: This is what my /etc/default/grub but I still get a 10 second countdown with the grub menu showing.

Answer (score 10):

You need to edit the file at `/etc/default/grub` to prevent showing the grub menu.

By default, the entries in that files look like this.

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

- Remove the `#` mark from second line, and
- Change the line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false` to `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true`.

After changes, the required portion of the file will look like this

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

- Then run `sudo update-grub` command in the terminal, and reboot to see the result.

Comment: I had this configuration but still the grub menu appears.

Comment: With this setting update-grub returns, 'Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported' and I still get a 10 second countdown while showing the grub menu. Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to 0 returns the same results also.

Comment: @zorkerz which version of ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Xenial Xerus but had the same behavior on 15.10

Comment: Note that this answer was written in 2012 and is out of date.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and none of the tips here worked! The only way was to change /boot/grub/grub.cfg manualy.
At some point of this file he makes the timeout goes to 10! So, just comment those lines

```
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
```

But, you can never do update-grub again, otherwise it will turn back to the same file, and timeout is going to 10 again!
Save the file (in vi you will need to force it even if you are su!). Restart the computer and it will work just fine!

Comment: Interesting, why not `if [ "${timeout}" = 10 ]; then
  set timeout=0
fi`  ? Or simply remove the if statement entirely and just leave `set timeout=0`?

Comment: This is put there from a template which can be disabled (the OS prober, as mentioned in Agustin's answer). You don't need to manually edit grub.cfg.

Comment: this worked for me in 14.04

Comment: -1. Any answer involving directly editing grub.cfg is just _wrong_. You must always reinstall grub when updating it, especially when upstream makes breaking changes, or you risk an unbootable system.

Answer (score 4):

I've found a simple solution to the problem.

```
  echo "
  set timeout_style=hidden
  set timeout=2" | sudo tee --append /etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

And update grub. It will overwrite timeout settings in grub.cfg, so it doesn't matter what you have in /etc/default/grub.
So I have hidden menu that can be invoked by shift for 2 sec.

Comment: This approach worked for me (grub 2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7 installed by Ubuntu 17.10) when none of the other solutions proposed on this page did (it's really bad luck that I tested this last :/). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

if you want to remove a boot entry just type in:

```
sudo update-grub
```

If that doesn't work, install the startup manager,
like so:

```
sudo apt-get install startupmanager
```

with startup-manager you can

1. choose with entry to boot in,
2. choose the resolution and, how long to wait before booting,
3. you can also choose 0 for automatic booting the default
   boot-entry

Comment: burg but he is taking about grub

Comment: sorry typo. it supposed to be sudo update-grub, i edited the answer

Comment: The only issue with this is that the version of Startup-manager I have doesn't show much options -[Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/rzFAx)

Comment: Im on 12.04 and i tried this but it already said "true" and it still shows up. The only other OS's I have are the failsafe and Memtest - that's it. I've already deleted my Windows Partition and updated grub and the menu still shows

Comment: next to "timeout in seconds" there is a box with the number 10 rename it to number 0

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line to `/etc/default/grub`:

```
GRUB_FORCE_HIDDEN_MENU="true"
```

Answer (score 3):

for all of you that have word splash in cmd line anything but hardcoding 0 for timeout won't work,,

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Try removing word ***splash*** from second last line, update and reboot,, voila, no menu :)

hth, krex

Answer (score 3):

Like [Agustin](https://askubuntu.com/a/540562/10800), I found that my issue was with the OS Prober. Doing one step better than his solution, I found [this gist](https://gist.github.com/LeahCim/9332432) that will let you have your OSes but still hide the menu. You just need to download those two files, put them into `/etc/grub.d`, and give them the same permissions as the other templates in that directory.

If you ever want to access your non-default OS, just hold down shift while booting up. That will show the menu.

Comment: that definitely seems like a bug to me. has anybody reported it???

Comment: True... maybe I'll get around to it at some point. No idea if there's one already there.

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, we could just put

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

into `/etc/default/grub` and be done with it. Unfortunately, at least on Manjaro, the file `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` overrides these settings. We could disable that file, but here's a better solution: create `/etc/grub.d/99_quiet` with these contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat <<EOF
set timeout_style=hidden
set timeout=0
EOF
```

(With this file, we don't even need to modify `/etc/default/grub` at all.) Make it executable and run `sudo update-grub` (or `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` if on Arch).

Reboot and GRUB will not display the menu or introduce any delay during boot. But, you can still get the menu if you hold down Shift after the hardware has turned on but before GRUB has started.

To understand what is happening here we must understand how GRUB configuration works. There is a `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file in a special DSL that is read by GRUB during boot. This can be written manually but it is preferred to generate it using `update-grub` (i.e. `grub-mkconfig`). That command uses `/etc/default/grub` and `/etc/grub.d` to generate the `grub.cfg`. The `/etc/default/grub` is sourced first, to set the configuration parameters for `update-grub` to generate the file. Then, each file in `/etc/grub.d` that is executable is *executed*, and its *output* is concatenated to the end of the `grub.cfg`.

For some docs, see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#Simple-configuration), but see also the actual shell scripts in `/etc/grub.d` and the resulting GRUB configuration `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: This did not work for me with Debian Bullseye (alpha).

Comment: @MichaelHerrmann Unfortunately that doesn't surprise me, different distros may have different default config files with different behavior. I think you'll have to investigate more thoroughly using the info in the last two paragraphs of the answer. Maybe you can update it with a note for your distro!

Comment: That worked for me on Ubuntu Mate 22.04, apart from the Shift part, even if I hold Shift just after boot grub doesn't appear (but TBH I don't bother much, I just wanted it to go away). THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

I've been seeing a lot of people saying that the suggested answers don't work for them. I tried several options and [this one worked for me](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/391#issuecomment-12264830):

Edit /etc/grub.d/00_header, and find:

```
if [ "\${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
```

Change it to...

```
if [ "\${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=10
```

And run update-grub.

Answer (score 2):

this took me a while but it payed off it was a mix of my own digging and answers above first make sure your `/etc/default/grub` and `/usr/grub/default/grub` are the same. then run `gksu gedit /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` near the top are the two lines we want but to find them search for styke and change that line to hidden then search for a timeout line it should be like if `timeout = 0` set to *10* delete that part from the if to end of file make sure you delete the end of file or your screwed and your grub config should log something like this this is mine just for example:

#### sets default boot to windows 8.1 pro

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="Windows 8 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)"
```

#### sets a five second window to hit shift so i can boot into Ubuntu

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
```

#### main fix for error just in case

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

#### sets style to hidden

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
```

#### default Ubuntu stuff

```
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Answer (score 2):

## For Ubuntu 20.04

Run the following command in `terminal`. It will create a **custom configuration file** for grub specifying the boot delay (setting *timeout=0* removed the grub screen)

```bsh
echo "set timeout_style=hidden
set timeout=0" | sudo tee boot/grub/custom.cfg
```

There is a nice explanation for this [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1270816/933983).

Comment: This one worked for me, on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1):

- Configure grub via `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
- Type end of the file:

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
```

- Save changes `CTRL` + `S`
- Exit `CTRL` + `X`
- Update grub menu `sudo update-grub`

Answer (score 1):

As of ubuntu 22.10 i recommend this:

edit the file /etc/default/grub:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Make sure you have this lines:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
```

Save and exit
run updater:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

**Attempt this at your own risk and only as a last resort!**

I tried editing `/etc/default/grub` and running `sudo update-grub` with no results.

Ended up editing `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` by hand, specifically,

```
...
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

set timeout=0
saved_entry="Ubuntu"
save_env saved_entry

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If setting `GRUB_TIMEOUT=` to zero in `/etc/default/grub` does not work, somewhere in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (the actual grub script) the timeout is getting changed. In the file which causes this, comment that line and run `update-grub`. This way `GRUB_TIMEOUT=` applies again and your change will persist resourcing grub.cfg.

How to: 
Start off by by trial and error: search for `set timeout` in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and change the timeout, reboot (do not run update-grub) and check if that changed the grub menu. If not, undo last edit and move to the next.

After you found the miscreant line in `grub.cfg` you need to look where it came from. Look for the `### BEGIN` & `### END` (`/boot/grub/grub.cfg` is generated by `update-grub` and sources files in `/etc/grub.d/`). In the vicious file, eg. `/etc/grub.d/00_header`, comment the corresponding line that sets the timeout and run `update-grub`. 
Now `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0` will skip the menu

Answer (score 0):

I have a dell XPS plus with **Ubuntu 22.04**. Bit similar to one of the answers above, none of the top answers worked for me. Following a thread [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=333778), I had to change the `/etc/grub.d/00_header` file.
The logic always flows through the `efi` branch and any other changes in other files does not work. I had to change the `timeout` value from 30 to 0. Then do a `sudo update-grub`.

```
if [ \$grub_platform = efi ]; then
  set timeout=${GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT:-30}
  if [ x\$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
  fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work it
here is my grub stuff

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0   
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -d -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to edit the file `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

In my case, my `/etc/default/grub` file was in this state

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

First of all, I added the line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true` to the file. But it was hiding the grub menu but still was taking 10s to start. Then, I changed `GRUB_TIMEOUT` value to `0` and it worked now.

Finally, the file looks like this:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Don't forget to run this command `sudo update-grub` in the terminal every time you make a change and save it. Otherwise, your changes won't be applied.

Answer (score -1):

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Set this if you hide grubmenu at boot! hidden-timeout has to be 0-10
# NOT recommend with dual-boot systems
# Type ESC/ENTER at boot to make grub-menu visible again! 
# in this case hidden-timeout has to be 3-10
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
```

solves the problem! s.grub2 @ubuntuusers! ;-)

Also it's possible to make grub-menu visible again during booting!

IMPORTANT if you have a crash and want to boot an older (and stable) Kernel!

(Tested with Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa which is based on Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: Please don't repeat [earlier answers](/a/562757).