# Dual Boot Default Question (W7 & Ubuntu)

Tags: 11.10, grub2, dual-boot, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)

I just installed Ubuntu 11.  on my computer but the default is Ubuntu.  How do I change it so that Windows 7 is the default?

Comment: Which does not contain a complete (and up-to-date) answer.  I've added one below (with link to 'duplicate').

Answer (score 3):

Adapted from: **[How do I set Windows to boot as the default in the boot loader?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52963/how-do-i-set-windows-to-boot-as-the-default-in-the-boot-loader)**

***For Ubuntu 11.x (or higher), with Grub2***

Find out what you boot options are called:

```
sudo update-grub
```

One of the entries should be 'Windows 7'.

Edit **/etc/default/grub** to set this as boot default:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

change:

```
    GRUB_DEFAULT=0
```

to:  (*for example*)

```
    GRUB_DEFAULT="Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)"
```

Save file, then (again) run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 1):

Run this in your terminal to open the GRUB configuration file in Gedit Text Edior:

```
gksudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

In that file, on line 13, you'll find this:

```
set default="0"
```

The number represents the default boot-item in the boot-menu, where the first item is 0. If Windows 7 is number 5 on your boot menu, change "0" to "5".
Remember to save the file before you close it.

Apply the changes by running this in the terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

To always have an easy way to change the default boot-item, change the default in the field to

```
set default=saved
```

Update grub using the command above (sudo grub-update), and then you can easily change the default boot item at any time  by using the command

```
sudo grub-set-default
```

followed by the number of the menu-item you want to set as default.

Comment: It is better **NOT** editing **/boot/grub/grub.cfg**.  It is created (from templates) when Grub2 content is updated.  It contains the following warning: '**DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE**'.

Comment: You are of course correct.

Comment: "sudo grub-update"? --> You mean `update-grub`?

Answer (score 0):

You can also download StartUp-Manager at Ubuntu Software Center, it comes with a GUI and it's simple to use! = )