# How to prevent GRUB from appearing after selecting Ubuntu from Windows' Dual Boot menu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.10 dual-boot. I have been trying to figure out a way to make Windows boot menu the only *boot menu* that comes up.

I used *EasyBCD* to add an option to boot into Ubuntu from the Windows boot menu, but I would like to make it so that *the GRUB screen doesn't show up* when I select the Ubuntu option.

I couldn't get it to work using GRUB Customizer. Anything I can try using those two programs or anything else?

Comment: if you want to hide the grub screen, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/111085/how-do-i-hide-the-grub-menu-showing-up-in-the-beginning-of-boot

Comment: Every time I change the grub settings, even via the terminal or editing the the .cfg, it makes it so that GRUB boots before Windows Boot Loader. Then I won't be able to boot into Windows unless I change the timeout setting back so I can select the Windows option.  It's a constant back-and-forth and I just want a simple dual boot setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured out my problem. Turns out I was clicking the "Write MBR" option every time I finished making changes in the GRUB Editor when all I had to do was click save so it did not overwrite the MBR but it did save my GRUB changes. Not sure what I did when editing the .cfg to make it overwrite the MBR but I'm sure it was my fault now, lol. Anyways, After using EasyBCD in Windows to add Ubuntu to the Dual Boot menu, clicking Write MBR, booting into Ubuntu and deselecting "look for other operating systems" and "show menu" in the general settings tab, and finally clicking Save (NOT Write MBR) I can avoid the GRUB menu when dual booting with Windows 7 and Ubuntu.