# update-grub Not Respecting Preferences from /etc/default/grub

Tags: boot, 13.10, grub2, configuration, bootloader

Following the advice from [an answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/153193) to [How do I remove or hide old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu or free space?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-or-hide-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu-or-free-sp/153193), I found myself having to put up with the GRUB boot menu every time I started the system. I followed [the instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/111093/82847) to hide the menu by editing `/etc/default/grub` and then running `update-grub`, and it seems to change `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` as I am able to verify that `set timeout=10` becomes `set timeout=0` after changing the relevant line in `/etc/default/grub`, but the menu still shows and it never times out!

Is there any way to get GRUB back to the way it was?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I hide the GRUB menu showing up in the beginning of boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/111085/how-do-i-hide-the-grub-menu-showing-up-in-the-beginning-of-boot).  Other answers there might work better for you.