# Why do I keep getting GNU GRUB?

Tags: boot, grub2

My computer is not a dual-boot it is just Ubuntu.

Why when I boot up do I get the GNU GRUB menu? It has options like recovery mode and stuff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I hide the GRUB menu showing up in the beginning of boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/111085/how-do-i-hide-the-grub-menu-showing-up-in-the-beginning-of-boot)

Comment: I believe he is asking _why_ a GRUB menu is shown, even when he isn't dualbooting.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is really not "Why do I get this?" but instead "How can I get rid of this?", try the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111085/how-do-i-hide-the-grub-menu-showing-up-in-the-beginning-of-boot).