# How to Remove the bootloader and automativally start ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, grub2, uninstall, bootloader, menu

Currently I am using Ubuntu alongside Windows 7.I have decided to get rid of windows and gain some extra disk space.That's easy. But How am i Supposed to remove the Bootloader at startup and directly boot Ubuntu.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/111085/how-do-i-hide-the-grub-menu-showing-up-in-the-beginning-of-boot

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the grub file by:

   `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. and change the following line:

   `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false` to:

   `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true`
3. Save and exit
4. Run `sudo update-grub`