# Would like to hide Grub menu

Tags: boot, grub2

First, sorry for my english (I'm french) !!

I've just bought a Dell Inspiron 13 2-in-1 laptop, installed Kubuntu 21.10 (no dual boot) but I've got a little problem with GRUB !

The grub menu still stays visible on boot, with a 30 seconds countdown...

I've first tryed to change the config with Grub customizer, no result.

Then I've modified the /etc/default/grub manually, plus a sudo update-grub, no result.

I've also tryed what's explained in this page about os_prober : https://gist.github.com/LeahCim/9332432 but still nothing...

Actually, my /etc/default/grub is

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Regards

EDIT :

Due to a suggestion here, I've changed the GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET= from false to true, but it's not better. Even changing GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT= from 2 to 0 didn't change anything.

In fact, whatever I change in /etc/default/grub, it seems to have no effects on Grub ; it's like if GRUB don't care about the /boot/grub/grub.cfg, or if grub.cfg don't care about /etc/default/grub, even after a "sudo update-grub".

EDIT 2 :

Whatever I try, nothing changes... I've tryed to find something in the grub.cfg but it's too difficult for me. I've seen "timeout=30" (line 109) which correspond to the 30 seconds countdown, but I don't know what to do with that neither how to change it. Could you help me, please ?!! Here is the file :

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${initrdfail}" = 2 ]; then
   set initrdfail=
elif [ "${initrdfail}" = 1 ]; then
   set next_entry="${prev_entry}"
   set prev_entry=
   save_env prev_entry
   if [ "${next_entry}" ]; then
      set initrdfail=2
   fi
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function initrdfail {
    if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -n "${partuuid}" ]; then
      if [ -z "${initrdfail}" ]; then
        set initrdfail=1
        if [ -n "${boot_once}" ]; then
          set prev_entry="${default}"
          save_env prev_entry
        fi
      fi
      save_env initrdfail
    fi; fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  # GRUB lacks write support for lvm, so recordfail support is disabled.
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod lvm
insmod ext2
set root='lvmid/WJ7HiC-1808-IY8B-ZnJg-m2JO-X2Sp-eon3xJ/0mBBLm-PWoV-07pO-6ItQ-H0vK-80Oc-7ctcrG'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/WJ7HiC-1808-IY8B-ZnJg-m2JO-X2Sp-eon3xJ/0mBBLm-PWoV-07pO-6ItQ-H0vK-80Oc-7ctcrG'  5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=fr_FR
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=0
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 0 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
if [ $grub_platform = efi ]; then
  set timeout=30
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
#set_background_image "images/tile.png";

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 0,0,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod lvm
    insmod ext2
    set root='lvmid/WJ7HiC-1808-IY8B-ZnJg-m2JO-X2Sp-eon3xJ/0mBBLm-PWoV-07pO-6ItQ-H0vK-80Oc-7ctcrG'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/WJ7HiC-1808-IY8B-ZnJg-m2JO-X2Sp-eon3xJ/0mBBLm-PWoV-07pO-6ItQ-H0vK-80Oc-7ctcrG'  5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-21-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-21-generic
}
submenu 'Options avancées pour Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 5.13.0-21-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.13.0-21-generic-advanced-5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod lvm
        insmod ext2
        set root='lvmid/WJ7HiC-1808-IY8B-ZnJg-m2JO-X2Sp-eon3xJ/0mBBLm-PWoV-07pO-6ItQ-H0vK-80Oc-7ctcrG'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/WJ7HiC-1808-IY8B-ZnJg-m2JO-X2Sp-eon3xJ/0mBBLm-PWoV-07pO-6ItQ-H0vK-80Oc-7ctcrG'  5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06
        fi
        echo    'Chargement de Linux 5.13.0-21-generic…'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-21-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Chargement du disque mémoire initial…'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-21-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 5.13.0-21-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.13.0-21-generic-recovery-5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod lvm
        insmod ext2
        set root='lvmid/WJ7HiC-1808-IY8B-ZnJg-m2JO-X2Sp-eon3xJ/0mBBLm-PWoV-07pO-6ItQ-H0vK-80Oc-7ctcrG'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/WJ7HiC-1808-IY8B-ZnJg-m2JO-X2Sp-eon3xJ/0mBBLm-PWoV-07pO-6ItQ-H0vK-80Oc-7ctcrG'  5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06
        fi
        echo    'Chargement de Linux 5.13.0-21-generic…'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-21-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr 
        echo    'Chargement du disque mémoire initial…'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-21-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 5.13.0-20-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.13.0-20-generic-advanced-5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod lvm
        insmod ext2
        set root='lvmid/WJ7HiC-1808-IY8B-ZnJg-m2JO-X2Sp-eon3xJ/0mBBLm-PWoV-07pO-6ItQ-H0vK-80Oc-7ctcrG'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/WJ7HiC-1808-IY8B-ZnJg-m2JO-X2Sp-eon3xJ/0mBBLm-PWoV-07pO-6ItQ-H0vK-80Oc-7ctcrG'  5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06
        fi
        echo    'Chargement de Linux 5.13.0-20-generic…'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-20-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Chargement du disque mémoire initial…'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-20-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 5.13.0-20-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.13.0-20-generic-recovery-5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod lvm
        insmod ext2
        set root='lvmid/WJ7HiC-1808-IY8B-ZnJg-m2JO-X2Sp-eon3xJ/0mBBLm-PWoV-07pO-6ItQ-H0vK-80Oc-7ctcrG'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/WJ7HiC-1808-IY8B-ZnJg-m2JO-X2Sp-eon3xJ/0mBBLm-PWoV-07pO-6ItQ-H0vK-80Oc-7ctcrG'  5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06
        fi
        echo    'Chargement de Linux 5.13.0-20-generic…'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-20-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr 
        echo    'Chargement du disque mémoire initial…'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-20-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 5.13.0-19-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.13.0-19-generic-advanced-5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod lvm
        insmod ext2
        set root='lvmid/WJ7HiC-1808-IY8B-ZnJg-m2JO-X2Sp-eon3xJ/0mBBLm-PWoV-07pO-6ItQ-H0vK-80Oc-7ctcrG'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/WJ7HiC-1808-IY8B-ZnJg-m2JO-X2Sp-eon3xJ/0mBBLm-PWoV-07pO-6ItQ-H0vK-80Oc-7ctcrG'  5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06
        fi
        echo    'Chargement de Linux 5.13.0-19-generic…'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-19-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Chargement du disque mémoire initial…'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-19-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, avec Linux 5.13.0-19-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.13.0-19-generic-recovery-5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod lvm
        insmod ext2
        set root='lvmid/WJ7HiC-1808-IY8B-ZnJg-m2JO-X2Sp-eon3xJ/0mBBLm-PWoV-07pO-6ItQ-H0vK-80Oc-7ctcrG'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='lvmid/WJ7HiC-1808-IY8B-ZnJg-m2JO-X2Sp-eon3xJ/0mBBLm-PWoV-07pO-6ItQ-H0vK-80Oc-7ctcrG'  5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 5a9194c9-d3ba-4f02-925e-a6bf54b49c06
        fi
        echo    'Chargement de Linux 5.13.0-19-generic…'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.13.0-19-generic root=/dev/mapper/vgkubuntu-root ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr 
        echo    'Chargement du disque mémoire initial…'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-19-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux_zfs ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/25_pre-os-prober ###
set timeout_bak=${timeout}
set timeout_style_bak=${timeout_style}
### END /etc/grub.d/25_pre-os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'UEFI Firmware Settings' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/35_post-os-prober ###
set timeout=${timeout_bak}
set timeout_style=${timeout_style_bak}
### END /etc/grub.d/35_post-os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

I've noticed in KDE partition manager that my NVME drive appears 2 times : 1st is /dev/nvme0n1 (with 2 partitions : /dev/nvme0n1p1 mounted on /boot/efi 512Mio FAT32 and /dev/nvme0n1p2 mounted on vgkubuntu 476,44Gio LVM2 PV) and 2nd /dev/vgkubuntu (with 2 partitions : /dev/vgkubuntu/root mounted on / 475,48Gio EXT4 and /dev/vgkubuntu/swap_1 980Mio linuxswap).
Is that normal ? Could it explain my problem with GRUB ?

Comment: It might be worth looking in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` to confirm that "whatever I change in /etc/default/grub, it seems to have no effects on Grub " If you change the value of the TIMEOUTs to 99, run update-grub, and don't find a 99 in that file, something deeper is going on. Or save the file to a .backup, make a trivial change in /etc/default/grub, run update-grub, then diff the files

Comment: Do you have multiple storage devices? Maybe the one GRUB looks at is not the one where you modify your config file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove or hide the GRUB boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18775/how-to-remove-or-hide-the-grub-boot-menu)

Answer (score 5):

I believe you need to change

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=2
```

to

```
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

You also need to run `sudo update-grub` after you make changes to the configuration file.

You definitely do not need GRUB customizer.  IMO GRUB customizer is a plague: most people would want boot to be as secure and stable as possible. Installing less stable, less secure, eyecandy to an essential low level utility that you only see for a few seconds is a bit silly. But one of the best things about Linux is that you have a lot of choices, including not-so-good ones. Hiding GRUB with configs is definitely the better option.

Comment: I wish I could give +100 just for the *Installing less stable, less secure, eyecandy to an essential low level utility that you only see for a few seconds is a bit silly.*

Comment: I agree for Grub customizer, but I needed to try that solution... I've already tried changing the GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT ; whatever I try, Grub always start showing the menu with a 30 seconds countdown...

Comment: There may be options that conflict with each other. There are a couple of different solutions where this has been asked before. See: https://askubuntu.com/q/618169. Always when editing configs like this make sure that you back up the original file so that you can restore any changes you have made.