# GRUB2 menu showing up with a single OS from time to time

Tags: grub2

I have a single OS install with Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS on a digital kiosk, with no keyboard attached.

The kiosk reboot every night, *but sometimes - rarely but it happends -* the grub menu shows up, asking with no timeout to choose between :

- Ubuntu
- Advanced option for Ubuntu
- Memory test (memtest86+)
- Memory test (memtest86=, serial console 115200)

The only solution to boot the kiosk is then to attach a keyboard and press enter.
There is my grub config :

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10 
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

How can I totally prevent grub menu from showing up and force Ubuntu to boot ?

What could explain that the grub menu is shown from time to time ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I hide the GRUB menu showing up in the beginning of boot?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/111085/how-do-i-hide-the-grub-menu-showing-up-in-the-beginning-of-boot)

Comment: I already read this question very thoroughly, and it did not help. The key question is why _from time to time_.  I think I know about obvious grub parameter, but I need some deeper insight. I thought about a physical memory  issue ? Could that force a grub menu ?

Comment: I'm not sure what is the cause of this issue, have you consider using something like `lilo`? I think it'll fit your situation, +1 for more luck.

Comment: Grub has a parameter that forces menu to appear on abnormal shutdown. That is so you can decide if you need to boot in recovery mode to make repairs or not. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2 See entry on GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT settings in grub.

Comment: @oldfred cool option, great hint.

Comment: @oldfred  I think you are right. The device is a unattended kiosk and it's not unusual that some guy just unplug the power socket, which then lead to a failed shutdown. You should post this as a answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grub has a parameter that forces menu to appear on abnormal shutdown. That is so you can decide if you need to boot in recovery mode to make repairs or not.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2

See section on Last Boot Failed or Boot into Recovery Mode. And 
See entry on GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT settings in grub and other info if grub entry does not work.

sudo nano /etc/default/grub

GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0

You may still need a Ubuntu live installer to run fsck or make other fixes as abnormal shutdown can cause issues that need fixes.