# Grub not showing windows partition

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, partitioning

My mom has a windows partition and a ubuntu 12.04 partition on her laptop, and we wanted to set grub to automatically load windows for ease of use. To do this I used steps from this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/66070/how-to-set-windows-bootloader-as-default-bootloader
the third answer (a two part tutorial) were the steps I had her follow, and now the windows partition is not showing in the grub.
I used update-grub and I got an error message after it showed some of the partitions; cannot find a grub drive for dev/sda1check your device.map.
So I'm thinking that when she went through the steps of the tutorial she didnt notice that and when she went through with the other steps it messed something up. That or the tutorial is what ultimately created the problem. 
So I have no idea how to make the ubuntu partition reappear as a selection in the grub menu (I think it has grub version 1.99 if that helps any)

***update***

I used a tool found on ubuntu's help section that fixed the issue.

Here is a [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows) to the tool I used.

Answer (score 1):

It'easy to setup your windows as a first Entry for OS load. type the following command in terminal.

**sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg**

then copy the menuentry for windows as shown in the sample code. The sample code is at below.Dont copy/cut this(sample) code. This is just sample to show that the menuentry code for windows in your grub.cfg file will look like this.

*menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-28CAFAF2CAFABAE0' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  28CAFAF2CAFABAE0
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 28CAFAF2CAFABAE0
    fi
    chainloader +1
}*

**Copy/cut similar to above code from your grub.cfg file and paste just below this line in grub.cfg file**

if [ "${linux_gfx_mode}" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi

This will make windows as a first entry at boot time.