# I need to see the BCDedit for a Windows10/Ubuntu install both by Wubi and by separate partition

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, uefi

I seem to have windows passing by on GRUB/Ubuntu. There's no Ubuntu folder under Windows. I can boot from firmware to Grub, then choose either OS. I removed Wubi/Ubuntu and reinstalled directly to the same partitions.

The windows Boot Manager did not create an entry for Ubuntu, so I need to create the entry.  Wubi puts `wubildr.mbr` on my system... but this is the wrong thing for EFI installs. I need the `shimx64.efi` so the created Windows boot in EFI might work.

I will make a copy of my boot with `bcdedit`, and point the entry to Ubuntu.

If this is incorrect, please tell me what to do next?

Comment: Just use bcdedit /v and copy it to paste here, pls?

Answer (score 20):

If you want to add an UEFI entry for Ubuntu with [bcdedit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709667%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), you can use the following commands as administrator:

List all BCD entries for UEFI:

```
bcdedit /enum firmware
```

Copy UEFI entry of "Windows Boot Manager" to create a new entry for Ubuntu:

```
bcdedit /copy {bootmgr} /d "Ubuntu Secure Boot"
```

Set file path for the new Ubuntu entry. Replace {guid} with the returned GUID of the previous command.

```
bcdedit /set {guid} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

Set optionally Ubuntu as first entry in the boot sequence. Replace {guid} with the returned GUID of the copy command.

```
bcdedit /set {fwbootmgr} displayorder {guid} /addfirst
```

Alternatively, you can use a script which does the job for you:

```
@ECHO OFF
rem add Ubuntu EFI entry

bcdedit /enum firmware

for /f "tokens=2 delims={}" %%a in ('bcdedit /copy {bootmgr} /d "Ubuntu Secure Boot"') do set guid={%%a}
bcdedit /set %guid% path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
bcdedit /set {fwbootmgr} displayorder %guid% /addfirst

bcdedit /enum firmware
```

Comment: This might help.  But The system start-up (Firmware) is already booting both the OS, as it should.  It's just windows doesn't acknowledge Ubuntu.

Comment: bcdedit entries "Firmware Application (101fffff)" should be visible in Windows menu [Advanced Startup Options](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2294-advanced-startup-options-boot-windows-10-a.html)->Use a device

Comment: bcdedit entries "Windows Boot Manager" as I used in my guide are not visible in this menu but the main function is to insert an entry to EFI menu of your firmware and change boot order if necessary

Comment: I tried the above commands. It indeed added a new entry, but adding it as first one (/addfirst) does not seem to be effective. It still boots Windows by default instead of grub.

Comment: [The Makers of easyBcd say:](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/uefi/) ”If your Windows PC is booting in EFI mode, Microsoft has blocked the loading of [...] This means that you can no longer use EasyBCD to add Windows 9x, XP [or] Linux entries.” – So I understand, with UEFI neither EasyBCD tool nor `bcdedit` will make this possible? Or am I missing something? (and I keep reading `bcdedit /set {UUID} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` accross the net, strongly sound like it _**is**_ possible...

Comment: Not work for fedora 38 workstation. It seems you still need to tell bcd where the core image of fedora is.

Comment: I had to quote the identifier, otherwise it gives me a syntax error: `bcdedit /set '{748e0a19-dbd3-11ee-a5c1-806e6f6e6963}'`. Am I the only one seeing this? None of the examples I've seen thus far are quoting it. I'm using Windows Powershell in Windows Terminal.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way for your intention should be [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html). EasyUEFI can create an entry for Ubuntu. **\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi** is the right file path for that entry. If necessary, you can also change the boot order.

Comment: I do not have an Ubuntu folder under windows.

Comment: @WLC The folder \EFI\ubuntu is on the EFI partition. The EFI partition is hidden under Windows, but EasyUEFI should also see this hidden partition.

Answer (score 0):

adding to @hakuna_matata 's answer
you should execute :

for other os default

```
bcdedit /displayorder {guid_of_os} /addfirst
```

for windows as default

```
bcdedit /displayorder {guid_of_os} /addlast
```

syntax

```
bcdedit /displayorder <id> [...] [ /addfirst | /addlast | /remove ]
```

you will get Ubuntu during boot on options