# Cant boot Ubuntu alongside windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I tried to install ubuntu on this notebook: http://www.mediamarkt.nl/nl/product/_peaq-pnb-s1415-i1n1-1438850.html alongside windows 10. First i couldnt get in the boot-menu but i know how to get there via system (in the meantime) but now i set windows on the bottom of the list, but it still overulls my ubuntu installation. Everytime i restart this notebook it goes straight to windows. I disable fast boot also, but nothing works.

I have it installed on 3 different pc's with windows 10 as well but i can't mannage to do it this time. Can someone help me?

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: Perhaps, my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/744809/386067) with EasyUEFI can solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use Wubi? Otherwise give the tool 'EasyBCD' a try. This is a free tool for Windows managing the behavior of you boot. If there's no Ubuntu entry, add it via the GRUB2 method, which should detect your Ubuntu installation automatically. Edit the order and the time for the bootmenu, don't forget to save everything and reboot to try. Be sure to have installed the GRUB2 bootloader in your Ubuntu installation, otherwise your Ubuntu won't be bootable so you should reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: I tried efibootmgr via "try Ubuntu" and changed everything and ended with putting windows at the bottom of the list. I don't know how to use grub2 I'm afraid but, I will find it out. I used the official 64bit version of Ubuntu.com and made the live USB via Ubuntu's gnome disk somewhat. Maybe I can give wubi a try.