# Ubuntu does not show up on the Windows Boot Manager

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

I have been spinning my wheels for hours.

Okay, so I have a Toshiba Satellite L745-S2410. I just used Rufus to Ubuntu-ify my 8GB USB drive. I have tried it with the BIOS/UEFI scheme, the GPT for UEFI scheme ,and now my last hope is the UEFI scheme.

When I pull up the Windows Boot Manager, all it shows is Windows 7. That's all its been showing this whole time. I have absolutely no idea what's going on. My computer once had a BIOS thing. I remember the menu being a solid teal and everything. Now its been replaced with this unusable boot manager.

Online forums I've read have talked about disabling secure boot. That option is not anywhere to be found on the Boot Manager. Or anywhere else for that matter.

I am pulling my hair out. Can anyone help? Thank you in advance.

Update: The UEFI scheme doesn't work either -_-

Comment: When you install ubuntu grub gets installed.. which should be ur default boot loader... windows is not smart enough to detect both os..

Comment: Also, 16.10 is not out yet so this is off topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need to see the BCDedit for a windows10/ubuntu install both by wubi and by seperate partition](http://askubuntu.com/questions/744697/i-need-to-see-the-bcdedit-for-a-windows10-ubuntu-install-both-by-wubi-and-by-sep)

Comment: Nope, none of this helped. @minigeek I don't know what you are talking about, sorry. Could you please elaborate? Also, I do not have a windows 10, I have a 7.

Comment: Just for clarity, you're unable to boot to the flash drive at all? I ask because your computer must have a BIOS or EFI system of some sort, and that system should load before the Windows Boot Manager. Usually, you can access the BIOS by repeatedly hitting the F2 or Delete key just after pressing the power button.

Comment: @OrestMercator why ubuntu in windows menu..!i dont know if it is possible in win7 or not..but ubuntu installs its own bootloader called grub..which allows to select in multiple os. Search for how to install or repair grub...first check in ur bios setup ..set highest priority to ubuntu boot loader...

Comment: And also for making bootable usb..use UUI for Linux and rufus for other os like windows... Google and download UUI and try installing again..if it helps.then rufus did something wrong in previous installation

Comment: I know i am late about 5 years but recently i faced the same problem and i solved by booting into linux mint via pendrive and running `boot repair` program. It automatically detected my windows 10 and linux mint os and configured the grub boot loader.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do cannot be done:  Windows isn't Ubuntu-aware so the Windows boot manager cannot display the Ubuntu boot manager: it just doesn't work that way...

It's your UEFI or BIOS subsystem that needs to display the Ubuntu Boot Manager (GRUB) which is Windows-aware, so GRUB *can* display the Windows boot Manager.

For more info on how to do that, look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: Well if you want to use gurb boot loader then there is a solution that will fix this linux and windows boot option not showing. i faced the same problem and i solved by booting into linux mint via pendrive and running `boot repair` program. It automatically detected my windows 10 and linux mint os and configured the grub boot loader.