# no windows 7 entry in grub after installing ubuntu

Tags: windows, grub2

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on a separate partition. Unfortunatelly after installation I couldn't see grub menu. Ubuntu starts automatically. Then I installed the boot-repair and repaired by this software my grub. Now I can see grub menu, but there is no windows entry. Just ubuntu.

Comment: please run the bootinfo script and add the output to your question: http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/760911/ here is info generated by boot-repair.

Comment: looks like you have overwritten the windows 7 boot loader - have a look at this forum entry fix your windows 7 boot loader (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1014708).  when you have done that, use this question & answer to use the windows boot loader: http://askubuntu.com/questions/62440/is-it-possible-to-boot-ubuntu-using-the-windows-bootloader/62442#62442

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved a Grub menu issue (Ubuntu 11.04 + Win7) with a software Grub Customiser. 
Good luck.

Comment: Hot to do that? I have installed this software. What should I do next?

Comment: IN Grub Customiser use Preferences button, than choose Advanced. From there change a default entry to number which corresponds to your Windows partition. (a numbering begins from zero  (0)).

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me several times when setting up multi-boot systems and I have always been able to fix it by running `sudo update-grub`.
Fortunately, update-grub is very straightforward and it will tell you exactly what it is putting in your GRUB menu, including Windows.  I have seen some CRAZY solutions to this problem *proposed* on the forums, I've even tried some of them (and they didn't work).  You really owe it to yourself to try update-grub before anything else though.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Ubuntu installation seems to do all kinds of wild things if you have multiple drives and such. Your GRUB was most likely installed on the wrong HD. I found it easiest to just partition the space myself using a GPARTED cd, and then reinstalling Ubuntu. There's an option when it asks you if you want to install it side-by-side with Windows that let's you manually select your partition and also the drive grub will be installed on.