# Windows 7 loader missing

Tags: grub2, windows, bootloader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [no windows 7 entry in grub after installing ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85443/no-windows-7-entry-in-grub-after-installing-ubuntu)

i just install Ubuntu 12.10 along side Windows 7.When booting it goes straight to ubuntu and skip grub.This problem occured since 12.04 on 11.10 everything went just fine. I run update-grub and Windows 7 is not listed.

Extra: My partition 
sda2 is ext4 Ubuntu 12.10 (46gb)
sda3 is swap Swap File (4gb)
sda5 is ntfs Windows 7 (50gb)
sda6 is ntfs Everything (400gb)

Answer (score 1):

try opening a terminal (either windows-key, type terminal, or ctrl+alt+T) and doing a:

```
sudo update-grub
```

fixed it for me...

Failing that, you might need to reinstall Grub completely.  There's some instructions here

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RecoveringUbuntuAfterInstallingWindows

I've used boot-repair in the past, but it looks like it might be as simple as just doing a

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

the important thing is to use the device (`sda`) not the partition (eg `sda6`)

Comment: already tried that...still doesnt work

Comment: any luck with the `grub-install` option instead?