# Can't boot windows after installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, bootloader

Okay, so today I installed Ubuntu. At the start of the installation, the installer didn't recognise Windows so I had to choose 'Something else' and create swap and root partitions. I then installed and now Ubuntu is working perfectly. However when I restart it automatically starts Ubuntu! I'm not given a start-up menu.

I have no idea what to do as I realise that even with a start-up menu, Windows won't be recognised. Does anyone know what I can do?

Thank you!!

EDIT: I think the answer is here [no windows 7 entry in grub after installing ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85443/no-windows-7-entry-in-grub-after-installing-ubuntu/85456#85456) but I just don't understand it.

From Vincenzo: ***"IN Grub Customiser use Preferences button, than choose Advanced. From there change a default entry to number which corresponds to your Windows partition. (a numbering begins from zero (0))"***

Can anyone explain what he means? Where can I find this number? Pleease help!

Comment: Try [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer).

Comment: @Mitch Okay, I'm in Grub customizer but Ubuntu doesn't recognise Windows so what should I do.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_beginner_books/unofficial_ubuntu_starter_guide/index_132.html).

Comment: Forget Windows....use Ubuntu exclusively! :-)

Comment: Yeah yeah. I just got into the Grub menu but there was no Windows option. How do I add it?

Comment: I recommend you post more information. Specifically, please run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) and post a link to the `RESULTS.txt` file that it generates. That will answer some critical questions. Without answers to those questions, answers to your question will be based on guesses.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the free tool [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Create a live disc and boot from it. From there you can add windows to your grub menu.

You can also find boot repair in your ubuntu live disc (which is essentially the same as your ubuntu install disc).

To boot from a disc, insert the disc in your machine, reboot and go to your boot menu (key combination to enter the boot menu should be displayed on boot). Select `boot from disc`.

Comment: Right for a reason unknown, I can't get into my BIOS when live disc is in drive so is there another way to do it? Or couldn't I just use Vincenzo's method?

Comment: Updated my answer, it might help you.

Comment: Ok, I have no idea why but when I restarted it loaded Windows. So is there anything I can do on the Windows side of things before trying that method?

Comment: Using a live disc is OS independent.