# Uninstall GRUB and use Windows bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, bootloader

I have Windows 8 pre-installed, and then I installed GRUB with Ubuntu. Ubuntu is not my thing, so now I want to remove it along with GRUB. From what I have learned, with UEFI, GRUB does not overwrite the windows bootloader in the EFI partition and is stored elsewhere. How would I remove GRUB and make my PC use the Windows bootloader instead? It should be noted that I created a separate /boot partition when installing Ubuntu.

Comment: So for those who have dual boot windows and ubuntu on the same or different disks and don't want the grub loader to show up but default to windows bootup instead and keep ubunut as a second option to start from the UEFI by boot overloading, jsut change the boot order in your UEFI to have windows as first and ubuntu as second and this will do the trick

Answer (score 470):

**This answer is for those with UEFI who have deleted the Ubuntu partitions before removing grub**

You will be doing this from Windows 10. No bootable media required.

Where `bootrec /fixmbr`, `bootsect /nt60` and the Ubuntu live with the `boot-repair` suggestions have failed, this has worked for me:

(This answer borrowed verbatim from [here](http://linuxbsdos.com/2015/09/05/how-to-delete-grub-files-from-a-boot-efi-partition-in-windows-10/))

1. Run a `cmd.exe` process with administrator privileges
2. Run `diskpart`
3. Type: `list disk` then `sel disk X` where X is the drive your boot files reside on
4. Type `list vol` to see all partitions (volumes) on the disk (the EFI volume will be formatted in FAT, others will be NTFS)
5. Select the EFI volume by typing: `sel vol Y` where Y is the `SYSTEM` volume (this is almost always the EFI partition)
6. For convenience, assign a drive letter by typing: `assign letter=Z:` where Z is a free (unused) drive letter
7. Type `exit` to leave disk part
8. While still in the `cmd` prompt, type: `Z:` and hit enter, where Z was the drive letter you just created.
9. Type `dir` to list directories on this mounted EFI partition
10. If you are in the right place, you should see a directory called `EFI`
11. Type `cd EFI` and then `dir` to list the child directories inside `EFI`
12. Type `rmdir /S ubuntu` to delete the ubuntu boot directory

Assuming you only ever had two operating systems (Win 10 & Ubuntu) you should now be able to boot directly to Windows without hitting the black grub screen.

Comment: I preferred this solution because I did not want to create a bootable device and it worked perfectly

Comment: rebooting after this caused me to recieve `Reboot and Select proper boot device`.

Comment: I figured out there was a submenu under bios `Boot` menu that was still referencing the deleted `ubuntu` grub item.  I set this to `Windows` and it worked.

Comment: Legend. This worked perfectly for me with a Razer blade stealth windows 10 with Ubuntu. I wanted to perform a complete factory restore for selling the laptop but needed to rid it of the bootmenu + ubuntu. Thanks

Comment: wow everything was exactly where you said it would be!

Comment: This worked for me, but I still have a question: does this actually remove grub or is in the background still something going on where grub hands things over to the windows boot loader?

Comment: @Bram I can't say for certain because I am just not knowledgeable enough, but I would hazard the guess that these steps actually delete the program files for Grub and therefore it would be "gone" gone.

Comment: This is the solution that works. MBR does not exist anymore because of GPT.

Comment: There's a video instructions here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTMCKOx5Jz0 if you need it.

Comment: I really messed up my previous install attempts so I got a notification on rmdir: "The file or directory \EFI\ubuntu\fw is corrupt and unreadable. Please un the Chkdsk utility."

Comment: -> which I did, although I had to force dismount *gulp*. Removal worked, but I still see ubuntu in my boot menu.

Comment: Hours of reading askubuntu and other stackexchange posts to finally hit this jackpot. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. I wish I could take credit for the answer, but alas I was just reposting steps that helped me. I'm glad it is working well for so many others!

Comment: Spent hours trying to get rid of GRUB, and this worked. Thanks for the solution. I'm on a Surface Pro 3 as well, so this works on Surfaces. If you run the /dir command again, you'll see that the ubuntu folder is deleted, so it does remove it for good!

Comment: For those having a scary "System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults" error, which causes a reboot loop, I had to F2 and select "Windows Boot Manager". Everything else is working like a charm!

Comment: So, I followed this perfectly, but upon restarting, my laptop was stuck in an infinite bootloop. I somehow managed to enter the BIOS and was able to select Windows. How do i prevent this from happening?

Comment: If all you want is to assign a drive letter for the EIF system partition, DISKPART is a bit unnecessarily complex – you can collapse steps 2–7 to a single `mountvol Z: /s` command.

Comment: This is the correct way to remove the boot entry

Comment: How to remove the assigned letter afterwards its showing in file explorer now

Comment: worked for me - deleted the ubuntu directory recursively but PC is going into BIOS - if i ESC or come out of it - it is shutting down and not booting into Windows

Comment: After a lot of workarounds this finally worked!!

Comment: Even though this is correct, this is not sufficient. The BIOS boot menu still has ubuntu in it. I removed it completely using `efibootmgr` application - https://askubuntu.com/a/923231/452738

Comment: got a error "Virtual Disk Service error:
Assigning or removing drive letters on the current boot or pagefile
volume is not allowed."

Comment: How do I restore the deleted EFI/ubuntu folder after doing these esteps?

Comment: I comment just to show how much I love you

Comment: I just wanted to add. If you don't want to see the volume after that, you can remove the letter in same diskpart. Select the volume and then just type `remove`

Comment: This works extremely well for cleaning up after any EFI-capable distro (such as Ubuntu) on an active system and stopped tricking my UEFI system. Thank you so much - this MUST be accepted as the answer, @mrolive

Comment: After following these steps, my computer can no longer boot at all. Previously I could boot windows from the grub terminal manually with the chainloader, but now even this does not work.

Comment: August 24th 2022, this still works. Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: This is incomplete. While it removes GRUB, it keeps the boot entry, unnecessarily slowing down boot. Unfortunately, this cannot be fixed from a Ubuntu live CD (as GRUB is no longer present). To fix the booloader, you need to run `bootrec /fixmbr` from a Windows CD, see https://askubuntu.com/a/654913

Comment: @armadadrive or anyone else - this totally worked on my Windows 11 install.  Is it now safe to reclaim space I allocated on the volume to the Ubuntu install? Don't want to make any assumptions.

Comment: December 5th 2023, this still works. Thanks a lot!
However, after doing the instructions and rebooting, I got an issue with a looping message "Reset System" at the beginning. I hard-stopped the computer pressing power button. Then I went to the BIOS pressing F2 (On a Lenovo laptop) and checked everything was ok. I then restarted several times to check and everything was working fine. So I am not sure what resolved the "Reset System" looping message, yet it works now.

Answer (score 90):

To restore Win 10 default bootloader follow these steps:

- Log into Win 10
- Open Command Prompt (Admin)
- `c:\> bootsect /nt60 <drive name>: /mbr`

`<drive name>` is the drive letter where the Master Boot Record (MBR) will be updated

For example to update **C** master boot record this is the command:

`c:\> bootsect /nt60 c: /mbr`

For more help about bootsect command see here - 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/bootsect-command-line-options

Comment: This is by far best solution, one minute, no install disk, usb needed

Comment: Some CISCO Talos annoyware was preventing me from doing this from within my OS, but as of Windows 10 you **no longer need an install disk** to do this. I have just done this operation without one; all you need to do is log out so you're on the log in screen, then you start holding down Shift, and press the power icon in the bottom right, then click Restart, now let go of Shift. This will open the same menu as the repair disk. You just have to go to Troubleshoot > Advanced options > Command Line and run `bootsect /nt60 c: /mbr`. Grub will be gone in an instant.

Comment: Does not appear to work for me. Grub appears until I press exit. 
   Updated NTFS filesystem bootcode.  The update may be unreliable since the
    volume could not be locked during the update:
        Access is denied.

\??\PhysicalDrive0

    Bootcode is only updated on MBR partitioned disks.  A different
    partitioning scheme is used on this disk.
Bootcode was successfully updated on all targeted volumes.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>

Comment: What does the /mbr do? I looked for documentation on bootsect, and I couldn't find anything about /mbr.

Comment: @PieTillIDie /mbr means Master Boot Record, surely this is about writing to the MBR, to overwrite what grub put there.

Comment: It's doesn't work for me 

Comment: Great Man, it works !!!

Comment: This worked for me. I did this from a win 10 recovery USB. You start on X:\Windows\System32 I ran `cd /d c:` and then `bootsect /nt60 c: /mbr` I got one error about access denied and one success message. Unplugged the USB and rebooted and it worked!

Comment: It worked without  hitch on my MBR-install.
I was confused, though, with the command line: c:\> further up is not what you enter. In my case it was some C:\windows32\something. The '>' is actually the last character of the command prompt. As user you start entering the command with the word 'bootsect'.

Comment: @ForceHero That does not work for me.  It yields "The update may be unreliable since the volume could not be locked during the update - access denied".

Comment: Solution to the error: **The update may be unreliable** since the
    volume could not be locked during the update:
        Access is denied. \??\PhysicalDrive0. 1. Reboot and press F12 to **open your bios** screen (It could be F8 or F2 depending on your model). 2. You should see Ubuntu Grub as the first bootloader and Windows as the second one. 3. Follow the instructions in your BIOS to change the order. This video might help - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46OofQo1W_4

Comment: This is confirmed to work with windows installation on mbr partition

Comment: not working in my case. UEFI Dell XPS desktop

Comment: thx you  save my day

Comment: Thanks! I can tell it works for Windows 11 as well

Comment: This only works on MBR partition tables.  If using GPT, you should use the answer from armadadrive.

Answer (score 33):

## Remove Boot Loader EFI / System Partion in Windows 10

### Quick Guide

Open PowerShell as Administrator

```
mountvol S: /S
S:
cd .\EFI\
dir
Remove-Item -Recurse Ubuntu
```

### Details

#### Administrator PowerShell

Enter ***powershell*** into the windows search of the start menu. Look for a blue icon with the label "**Windows PowerShell**", **right click** on the that and select **"Run as Administrator"** within the context menu.

#### Mount EFI/System Partition As Volume

To **Mount the EFI System Partition on the given drive** use the **[mountvol command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mountvol)** by using the **/S** parameter. You can chose any free drive letter you want. For example "S".

```
mountvol S: /S
```

#### Access Mounted Volume

Now the partition is mounted. We can **access the mounted volume by changing to the drive by the [cd command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cd) and the drive letter S: as parameter**

```
cd S:
```

To ensure we are at the root of this volume we should execute:

```
cd \
```

We can now utilize the [dir command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir) to list the directories under the current path to ensure the we are indeed on the UFI partition drive.

```
dir
```

The output should look similar to this:

```
Directory: S:\


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       2019-01-17     12:55                EFI
-a----       2018-10-16     10:57             31 startup.nsh
```

### Delete Boot Loaders

Your boot loaders are location in the **EFI** directory.
Change to it by using the [cd command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cd) and list the entries via the [dir command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir).

```
cd .\EFI\
dir
```

Your **output depends on the boot loaders** you have installed, here is a **example with Windows and Ubuntu**.

```
Directory: S:\EFI


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       2018-12-06     06:55                Ubuntu
d-----       2018-12-05     05:21                Microsoft
d-----       2019-01-17     12:55                Boot
```

Now you can **delete unwanted loaders via the [command Remove-Item](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.1) and the parameter -Recurse.**

**DO NOT DELETE THE BOOT DIRECTORY OR THE WINDOWS DIRECTORY!**

```
Remove-Item -Recurse .\ubuntu
```

Comment: Note from present self to future self: *This is the ONLY solution that worked*

Comment: In PowerShell instead of command 'rd /S ubuntu', I had to use 'Remove-Item ubuntu'.. Thanks for sharing this solution!

Comment: This is the correct answer for systems with EFI, especially if you installed linux on a separate drive which is the optimal way to go. Goodness, so many complicated answers out there and its really simple to do.

Comment: Did you maybe mean to write `rd /s ubuntu` instead of `rd /S ubuntu`? There is no `/S` option in the manual of rd and it didn't work for me. I used `Remove-Item ubuntu` instead, like @BlueDev did.

Comment: There was still an "Ubuntu" entry left in the boot menu after I did this so I just deleted it.

Comment: @geras I changed the command. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @geras There is still an Ubuntu entry left in the Boot menu. How did you delete that?
The commands I executed:

`mountvol S: /S`
`S:`
`cd .\EFI\ ` 
`dir`
`Remove-Item -Recurse .\ubuntu`

Comment: When you are sure that you are not having a typo in the folder name, you could try adding the `-Force` paramter to the `Remove-Item` command: `Remove-Item -Recursive -Force .\ubuntu`

Comment: mountvol S: /S
> The parameter is incorrect.

Comment: What windows version are you using? I tested `mountvol S: /S` on Windows 10.0.19042.1889 and it works fine.

Answer (score 24):

You can restore the Windows bootloader with a Windows 8/8.1 DVD. These instructions are inspired by Manindra Mehra's answer, but I expanded it with full working details (verified with a Windows 8.1 DVD).

1. Put the DVD in your optical drive and boot from it.
2. Press a key when it displays `Press any key to start from CD or DVD`.
3. Select your language etc. and click `Next`.
4. Click `Repair your computer`.
5. Click `Troubleshoot`.
6. Click `Advanced Options`.
7. Click `Command Prompt`.
8. In the command prompt window, type `bootrec /fixmbr`
9. Click the red `X` to close the command prompt.
10. Click `Turn off your PC`.
11. Turn the PC back on and it should boot directly into Windows.

This leaves the Ubuntu partition on your hard drive or SSD. To remove it:

1. Hit `Windows`+`X` and select `Disk Management`.
2. Find the Ubuntu partition. It will probably be a large partition without a drive letter.
3. **Be sure you have the correct partition!**
4. Right-click the partition and delete or reformat it with a Windows filesystem.

Answer (score 20):

To do so you will need a windows installation cd/dvd

1. put it in your optical drive and boot from it
2. on the installation screen where it asks you to install windows, click on *Repair Your Computer* on the lower left corner of your screen
3. Now go to command prompt (It probably will show a window saying "Trying to repair windows automatically", close it) and type `BootRec.exe /fixmbr`
4. after it finishes GRUB is gone and you can now boot into windows directly
5. you have an Ubuntu partition left in your computer, that doesn't show in "My Computer", to access that, right click on "My Computer" and Select "Manage" and go to "Disk Management"
6. Select the Ubuntu partition and format it to a file system that windows can use.

Comment: For completeness, also [remove ubuntu from the efi boot menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi). I think this should be added as step 7.

Comment: Please fix step 3 by explaining how to go to command prompt. Michael Geary's answer is more complete. This answer led me to reset my PC unnecessarily once because I didn't know how to go to command prompt.

Answer (score 13):

With UEFI you have both a Windows folder & an Ubuntu folder in the efi partition. the UEFI reads the efi entries and adds them to its own NVRAM to remember them. You have to remove ubuntu folder from efi partition first or UEFI will re-add it. Then you have to remove UEFI entry from UEFI.

You should have these folders in the efi partition. Delete only the ubuntu folder. Live installer should show folders. And if only Windows you have to mount from inside Windows the efi partition as it is not normally mounted.

```
/EFI/Boot
/EFI/Microsoft
/EFI/ubuntu
```

You should not have to install Ubuntu but can use live installer DVD or flash drive. Some UEFI systems may let you do the UEFI edit from UEFI menu.

from liveDVD or flash and use efibootmgr

```
sudo efibootmgr -v
```

The "-v" option displays all the entries so you can confirm you're deleting the right one, and then you use the combination of "-b ####" (to specify the entry) and "-B" (to delete it). Examples #5 is delete:

```
sudo efibootmgr -b XXXX -B
```

See also

```
man efibootmgr
```

Comment: This was helpful in directing what I needed to do. I could delete the ubuntu partition in Windows using informaition from here: http://superuser.com/questions/662823/how-do-i-mount-the-efi-partition-on-windows-8-1-so-that-it-is-readable-and-write

Comment: From a live usb stick, starting with efibootmgr -v, then using -b 0002 -B worked for me after 'fixmbr' from windows didn't seem to work, and that solution seemed a lot easier than some of the other solutions.

Comment: This is mind-blowingly the easiest way to get rid of a boot entry. THANK YOU. Links are broken by the way.

Comment: Removed broken links, add suggestion for example in man page for efibootmgr. A few Manufacturers, do not recognized efibootmgr and then your only choice is to go into UEFI menu (not UEFI one time boot menu) and on boot tab edit entries.

Answer (score 9):

No CD's, USB's, DVD's. No long tutorials.

On UEFI all you have to do is:

**`Place Windows boot entry in NVRAM as first.`**

How to do this - several solutions.

Easiest solution is to use firmware functionality and reorder NVRAM boot entries.

Comment: For people wondering where to find this, go to your BIOS settings.

Comment: Thanks! So easy.

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me is:

1. Boot to Windows
2. Win + X
3. Command Prompt (as admin)
4. `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi`
5. Reboot

Comment: Did not work on Windows 11 as of today

Answer (score 3):

You can also use a USB memory stick for this job. It takes three applications: Unetbootin, FreeDOS and Testdisk for DOS.

1. First download Unetbootin and use it to make a bootable USB memory stick. Choose Freedos when prompted for a distribution to install on it.
2. Download Testdisk for DOS (don't pick the beta, but pick the stable version).
3. Unzip the files testdisk.exe and CWSDPMI.exe, and put them on the bootable memory stick (not in a folder, just straight on it).
4. Boot your computer from the memory stick. At the Default window, simply press Enter.
5. Now FreeDOS is being launched. Choose: `FreeDOS Safe Mode (don't load any drivers)` and Press Enter.
6. Then type: `C:` and Press Enter.
7. Now type: `testdisk` and Press Enter.
8. Select `[No Log]` and Press Enter.
9. Select the hard drive concerned: usually the second option (the first option is the memory stick itself) and Press Enter.
10. Select `[Intel]` and Press Enter
11. Select `[MBR Code]` and press Enter. When prompted, type `y` (yes) and press Enter again.

Now you're done! Reboot your computer normally. Your computer should boot up Windows now.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! As it appears this was a copy paste, please consider linking to the original page at the end of your answer.

Answer (score 2):

## If All Else Fails!

---

The guy above me's method  does not work on newer EFI computers. I solved the problem. Here is how I did it. WARNING, you have to reinstall Linux / grub first!

Steps: (this is if nothing else works and takes a long time)

1: Reinstall Ubuntu / Linux mint (this is just so you can use GRUB to boot into Windows).

1.5: Restart and boot into windows (if you can't boot to Windows, then live boot from the CD or USB and run the following in a console:

If you have a windows repair disk you can select the UEFI firmware option and load Windows from there (to avoid reinstalling Linux)

### Boot repair (if needed right now)

---

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

1g: Select recommended repair and follow the on screen instructions.

2g: After your done, reboot. You should see the grub menu,  even though you can boot to Windows from here, this is not what we want yet... But find the option that boots into Windows.

---

2: Once your booted into Windows, run your disk partition editor and delete All partitions related to Linux / grub. Especially make sure the small grub partition is removed. Reboot

2.5: Make sure the windows loader is the first selected boot device. (most likely is). Disable the Ubuntu option. Continue boot.

3: If you've done everything right up to this point you should see (depending on your computer) your splash screen for a second and then it will turn into an error screen saying that there was an error with the boot. ("Winload.exe is missing or corrupted" most likly).

3.5: Don't be alarmed (I was). The next step will restore your original bootloader.

4: Restart and boot to your Linux CD or USB.

5: Once booted, run boot repair commands from above again. This time when running it. It will act differently, there is no grub bootloader detected to reinstall and should run faster than before.

6: Once complete, restart.

7: Enjoy your GRUB free system!

This worked for me when nothing else did, I ran bootrec.exe. Nothing worked. This saved my computers life. Hope it saves yours!

Comment: I did this and It didn't work at all.

Answer (score 2):

For system with GPT partition table, the method provided by @Ganesh Kondal won't work. Using `bootsect /nt60 C: /mbr` will show that it worked while it really doesn't. Using `bootrec /fixmbr` will lead to error that "the system cannot find the file specified". If any of the above situation applies, do the following (Using Windows 10 as an example):

1. at log in prompt, hold shift, click on power button, choose restart, let go of shift
2. choose troubleshoot -> advanced options -> command line
3. at command line, type in `bcdboot <drive name>:\windows`

for more detailed information, also look at this webpage:https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/74226-bootmgr-error-cant-find-fix.html

Answer (score 1):

It may be impossible to do that. The temporary solution is to remove the GRUB menu, and use BCDedit.

Extract from ubuntuhandbook (https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/06/hide-grub-boot-menu-ubuntu-20-04-lts/)

> You can do the job easily via Grub-Customizer (available in Ubuntu Software) under General Settings tab. However, you need to also disable “look for other operating systems” option.

> Any time you want to show the Grub menu, press ESC while booting up will NO longer show dual-boot (multi-boot) systems other than Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I have followed the instructions of the 2nd answer on this thread but after that my pc was stuck in a boot loop. Running the command
`bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi` fixed it for me since my Windows Boot Manager path was pointing to grub.

PS: I thought this would help people who are saying that their computer is stuck in a boot loop after that. I could have added a comment under that but need 50 rep so adding an answer.