# Removing GRUB2 from Dual Boot

Tags: dual-boot, uefi

I have dual booted Windows 10 along with Ubuntu. It is an efi system.

Now, I want to remove Ubuntu. Firstly, I removed the partition then I tried to remove grub by using Windows installation disk. But it wasn't successful. I also tried to remove efi folder and wasn't successful at this also.

I still have a GRUB2 command line while booting.

Please suggest on removing this option.

Comment: This is a Windows related problem. Since you removed Ubuntu you will need to fix this from within Windows. In the old days it would be "fixmbr". How this is done in W10 is off topic ;) Besides that: dupe http://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Comment: I don't think this is off-topic for the reasons Rinzwind stated, since the problem was caused by Ubuntu. That said, it *is* a duplicate of his stated question.

Answer (score 2):

Although we are way more interested in helping people that are using or want to use Ubuntu ...

Boot from Ubuntu installation media and select **Try Ubuntu without installing**.

When the desktop appears, open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute:

```
sudo mount /dev/sd* /mnt
sudo rm -rf /mnt/EFI/ubuntu
```

Note: * = EFI partition

You can identify the EFI partition with GParted, which is included in the installation media.

Answer (score 0):

You should boot windows recovery mode -> insert your windows pwd -> troubleshooting -> advanced options -> fix problems that prevent windows from booting properly (it's my translation, since I found a solution for your problem but it's in italian)
here's the [link](http://www.ilsoftware.it/articoli.asp?tag=Fix-MBR-per-ripristinare-boot-di-Windows-e-avvio-del-computer_12012)

It's in italian but you figure it out what to do by watching the pictures. Have a try.