# How to totally remove ubuntu from boot menu after Windows dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, grub-efi, ubuntu-core

I dual booted windows 10 and ubuntu. Now, I don't want the Ubuntu. So I deleted the ubuntu partitions. Next, I used the Windows recovery drive to run `bootrec.exe /fixmbr` in cmd.So If I power my pc now, it boots to Windows directly but there is a problem: Ubuntu still exists when I check the boot menu.How can I remove it?

In the Boot menu I see: -

- OS Boot Manager
- ubuntu(ST500LT012-1DG142
- Boot from EFI File

When I select the ubuntu option: I see

> GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-22ubuntu1
>
> Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported....

When I press tab, it shows a list of commands to enter.

Comment: What devide are you using? Maybe you can remove it by accessing BIOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uninstall Grub and use Windows bootloader](http://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader)

Comment: To Faraday, hello Sir, when i tried doing this through **msconfig** and when i hit enter and go to **boot** tab it doesn't shows any **ubuntu record**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've  gotten the solution https://askubuntu.com/a/63613/410771

You should be able to do this via a Live Ubuntu CD.

Install efibootmgr:

```
sudo apt-get install efibootmgr
```

Then add to the kernel efi support

```
sudo modprobe efivars
```

Then run `sudo efibootmgr` to check your boot entries. It will return something like this:

```
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 2001,0003,0005,0006,0000
Boot0000* Lenovo Recovery System
Boot0001* EFI Network 0 for IPv6 (B8-88-E3-84-F3-EF)
Boot0002* EFI Network 0 for IPv4 (B8-88-E3-84-F3-EF)
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0004* EFI USB Device (SanDisk)
Boot0005* ubuntu
Boot2001* EFI USB Device
```

Then delete the option you dont want. In this example, Ubuntu is entry 5. the following could be called to delete entry 5 and remove it from the BootOrder.

**(CAUTION: Before executing the following command make sure you enter the correct Boot entry number)**

```
sudo efibootmgr -b 5 -B
```

Further details described here: http://linux.die.net/man/8/efibootmgr

**Note: as for anything that changes your bootloader, please ensure you have a good disk image that you can boot with.**

Now you should also delete the `ubuntu` subdirectory in the EFI partition to prevent the UEFI firmware from restoring the entry into the BootOrder.

To do that, first find your EFI partition. Run `sudo fdisk -l` to see the partitions on all attached drives. The EFI partition has `EFI Partition` under the Type column.

Suppose your EFI partition was `/dev/sda2`, then mount it on an empty folder anywhere.

```
    sudo mkdir /mnt/efipart
    sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/efipart
```

Now we have to find the directory `Ubuntu` or any other distro's name in this partition. It is mostly under `EFI/distro_name`.

Remove that directory and its contents by (**PLEASE MAKE SURE YOU ARE DELETING THE CORRECT DIRECTORY**) `sudo rm -r ubuntu`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly - you have Ubuntu option in boot menu on startup.
The easyest way is to press **Win + R** and type **msconfig** and hit Enter.
In window that appears go to **Boot** tab select ubuntu record and press **Delete**
Then mark the checkfield **Make all boot setting permanent**
Then press Yes to conform and reboot.

Comment: I followed this but it's only Windows that's listed. In other words, Ubuntu isn't in the list.

Comment: Then please provide some more information where you see the Ubuntu? Maybe screenshot?

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: Try this method: http://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Comment: Great, I'm glad it helped!