# Deleted my ubuntu partition off windows. The system will no longer boot up (Only boots into grub)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

so I accidentally deleted my ubuntu hard drive off windows and I created a new partition and now my system will not properly boot up into Windows. I have to hit F12 and click on the Windows Boot Manager option , otherwise my system will boot into GRUB.
I did some research on the forums and found that I have to get a Windows 10 pendrive and just go to the repair, and insert in the command line both  "bootrec.exe /fixmbr" & "BootRec.exe /fixboot" but that does not seem to solve my problem. Any thoughts on this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is the question? What is the current goal, stated in none-vague terms? Do you want Grub restored? Do you want Ubuntu restored? Do you want Windows bootloader restored?

Comment: I am trying to restore my Windows bootloader.

Comment: What does it have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: If newer UEFI system: Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well go to an live cd and try

---

https://www.boyans.net/dual-boot-repair-windows-10.html
or

---

[Uninstall Grub and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Since nothing else works for me, I went ahead and reinstalled Ubuntu, then followed this tutorial http://askubuntu.com/a/497690/477176 from the second link, and everything seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows) says to run `bootrec /RebuildBcd` first, before the two other commands you tried. It also says you might have to run

```
bootsect /nt60 SYS
```

or

```
bootsect /nt60 ALL
```

after the other three commands.

Comment: Just tried that. Doesn't seem to change anything.