# remove Ubuntu from dual-boot system

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, uefi, 15.10

I had Ubuntu 15.10 and Windows 10 on the same drive. I wanted to remove Ubuntu so I did following steps:

- go to disk manager and remove two Ubuntu partitions and add free space to windows partition.
- run Windows USB installer with command line ant type: `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`

The thing is that Ubuntu boot options were not removed from my BIOS. I had to manually switch it to Windows boot because the computer was starting with a GRUB command line.

Is there a way to safely remove these bot options?

Comment: Does the Win-10 `bash` command give you access to grub-mkconfig & update-grub? (I don't have Win-10 so can't test this)

Comment: If you can boot to Windows, you can use [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) to create, delete, edit, and change the order of EFI boot entries.

Comment: You can use software to remove GRUB.

Comment: If UEFI you can also houseclean UEFI entry & /EFI/ubuntu folder in ESP. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader/497720#497720

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new EFI system the windows and Linux bootmanager are separated. To use the windows boot manager as the default one instead of grub, just select it as the default EFI boot manager in the BIOS settings and you'll automatically boot into Windows by default

Comment: I did this already. But how to remove Ubuntu boot options from BIOS?

Comment: First of all, if you have selected windows boot manager as your default boot manager, you wouldn't see grub when you boot up. Anyways, even if you're using grub, you can try booting from a live image and then reinstalling grub (try out boot-repair)

Comment: I am not seeing GRUB but there are still Ubuntu boot options in BIOS. Thats what I want to remove,,,

Comment: Oh. That I'm not sure. I believe removing the .efi file from the EFI partition should remove it from the BIOS list. Not sure though. Google it

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to remove ubuntu safely from dual boot is to use EaseUS partition master before deleting Ubuntu partitions.

1. Download and install EaseUs partition master on Windows.
2. Select the hard disk and right click and choose **rebuild MBR**
3. Choose your OS and click on apply button at the top bar.

Now you can delete or format Ubuntu partitions.