# Installing Ubuntu 16.04 on separate disk but it behaves weird

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, ssd

04 yesterday. Here is my system:

- SSD1 : 256G SSD (Window installed)
- HDD1 : 2TB HardDrive
- SSD2 : 120G SSD (Ubuntu installed)

I originally had windows and got spare SSD so I decided to install ubuntu in it.

Everything worked well and in my BIOS I boot with SSD2 (Ubuntu) it doesn't boot.

And when I chose SSD1 as boot disk, Ubuntu boot manager pops up and ask me to choose what OS I want to boot.

What I expected was, when I want to boot with windows, I go to BIOS and choose SSD1, and when I want to boot with ubuntu I chose SSD2 as a boot disk.

But now it seems there is grub in SSD1 and it manages everything.

I want to separate 2 operating systems so there is no problem when I remove SSD2.

Do I have to remove grub from SSD1 and reinstall ubuntu in SSD2?

Answer (score 0):

If you remove SSD2 you won't have a problem unless you tell grub to boot from it. The grub menu options are built on SSD1 so even though it displays the menu options it doesn't know SSD2 isn't there until you pick the menu option linked to it.

It's real easy to test. Simply remove SSD2 and reboot. Grub will let you pick OS's on SSD1 and HDD1. If you try to pick Ubuntu on SSD2 some sort of error will occur but you can't break SSD2 programs because it's unplugged.

Then power down, reattach SSD2 and power up. You'll be able to pick Ubuntu on SSD2 again.

Comment: Ok thank you! it helped!! but is there any ways to remove grub from my SSD1 and let grub know only about SSD2?

Comment: this is because for future. I currently have window7 which is kind of outdated. so when I have to change my window OS, window installer will blow all SSD1 disk and grub right?!

Comment: Windows only consumes the amount of SSD1 you allocate to it plus the grub boot loader at the beginning of SSD1. The main part of grub is stored with Ubunutu on SSD2 and it is used by `boot-repair` to generate a new grub boot image on SSD1.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I tried to remove grub boot loader and I couldn't find how... to use bootrec.exe I need a repair disk but i don't have it any suggestion how to remove it from cmd or something?

Comment: Try this link: [BootRec.exe /fixmbr](http://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader)