# Unable to Replace GRUB Bootloader with Windows 10 Bootloader from Windows 10 installation USB

Tags: dual-boot, bootloader, windows-10

I had Kali Linux, Ubuntu, and Windows 7 installed alongside each other with a GRUB bootloader to boot into each, until I upgraded to Windows 10. I expected that would overwrite the bootloader, but it didn't. I have since deleted the Ubuntu partition from Windows, but I'm prevented from doing so with the Kali partition. Even though I've deleted the Ubuntu partition, the GRUB bootloader still has an entry for it. I've tried running linux bootrepair several times to no avail. I really just want to uninstall the GRUB bootloader and replace it with a Windows 10 bootloader.

So, I have tried following the steps of the answer from [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader). However, when I run the command `bootrec.exe /fixmbr` I receive an error stating that the system cannot find the file specified.

Running the command `bootrec.exe` does seen to show the correct dialogue giving me the commands and what they should do. However, `bootrec.exe /fixboot` also gives an error stating that the system cannot find the file specified.

Also, running the commands `bootrec.exe /scanos` and `bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd` each find 0 Windows installations

Answer (score 0):

First download [bootsect.exe](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35619242/Bootsect.exe/%22bootsect.exe%22') into the Download directory.

press the windows key, type cmd.exe and on the result (The command prompt) start it as an "Administrator" by right clicking on the cmd icon, and select Run as Administrator.

In the new cmd.exe window, cd to your download directory. for example cd C:\Users\Lalu Patel\Downloads. _assuming your user name is "Lalu Patel".

Then enter this command. bootsect.exe /nt60 ALL /force /mbr. Restart your system to see that, Windows is automatically loading without grub.

Then in Windows

```
Open the Control Panel (All Items view), and click on the Administrative Tools icon. then close the Control Panel window
Click on Computer Management in Administrative Tools, then close the Administrative Tools window.
In the left pane under Storage, click on Disk Management. see this.
Select the the partition with unknown type. it is the Ubuntu partition. Right Click -> Delete partition.
Now the former Ubuntu partition becomes an unallocated space.
Select the left partition of the new unallocated space.
Right click on the partition -> click on Extend Volume.
Click on the Next button.

Type in how many MB (1 GB = 1024 MB) you want to use from the unallocated space to extend the selected partition (step 5) into, then click on the Next button.see this.

Note: If you want to use all of the unallocated space to extend into, then type in the maximum available space shown for the unallocated space.

Click on the Finish button. You're done.
```

Source: [bootsect](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744577%28v=ws.10%29.aspx/%22bootsect%22), disk management