# How to remove "Ubuntu" from Boot Menu after deleting Ubuntu partition in Windows 10 (Dual Boot)

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10, bootloader, bios

I have recently installed dual-boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. After messing around with Ubuntu, I decided it was time for a clean re-install.

I booted back into Windows 10 and deleted the Ubuntu partition (two of them) and they were converted back to `free space`.

Upon reboot, I got into a black screen with `Grub >` command line. (Note: not Grub rescue). Not knowing what to do, I did a force shut down.

Next, I attempted to boot my machine again, this time pressing F2 to get into BIOS. I was lucky that I could change the Boot Order to get `Windows Boot Manager` back on top of the list, instead of `Ubuntu`. I successfully booted back to Windows 10.

Now, this is where my issue differs from the rest (I did some research on similar topics before posting). Now, I can boot back into Windows 10.

My goal is to remove Ubuntu **and reinstall it** for a clean-slate. I have already deleted the Ubuntu partitions. However, now the `Ubuntu` selection remains lingering in my Boot Menu. Hence, how can I remove it?

Comment: Here is a easy program to do that. http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html

Comment: @EODCraftStaff Am I right to assume that I should use this program to just make a `deletion` of the `Ubuntu` boot option? May I also ask if there's any thing else I need to do before I reinstall back Ubuntu on the free space partition for a clean installation (because I realised deleting the partition right away is too abrupt, nothing like the steps shown here: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2016/04/how-to-remove-ubuntu-from-computer-dual.html?m=1)

Comment: You can use it to edit and prioritize your boot options also but I have found under the latest update of Windows 10, Every Windows update rewrites the boot manager file and I must edit the boot order each time in the CMOS. If your still on the Version prior to April 11th, 2017 it works marvelous. I have a post on MS Forum about this but it remains unanswered, Sry.

Comment: Thanks @EODCraftStaff. :-) I've solved my problem using USB-Booted-Ubuntu Terminal.

Comment: I do not believe it to be a duplicate, for the post cited immediately above does not explicitly show how to edit GRUB to remove the remnant listing for the Ubuntu which was removed.

Comment: @DavidFoerster I agree with K7AAY. The [linked page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on) mostly speaks about MBR but this seems to be a UEFI case with an Ubuntu residue in the EFI partition. **@ Keith OYS** Can you check you are using UEFI?

Comment: @DavidFoerster This is indeed a different issue, like K7AAY explained.

Comment: @Melebius Yes, I am using `UEFI` as listed under `BIOS Mode` in `MSINFO32`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've successfully executed this solution below to my problem:

1. In BIOS, change Boot Sequence to allow booting from USB (containing Ubuntu)
2. In GRUB, select *Try Ubuntu without installing*
3. Once in Ubuntu, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to bring up Terminal
4. Type `sudo efibootmgr` to list all the entries in Boot Menu. If the command doesn't exist, then do `sudo apt install efibootmgr`.
5. Find `Ubuntu` in the menu and note down its boot number e.g. `1` in `Boot0001`
6. Type `sudo efibootmgr -b <boot number> -B` to delete the entry from Boot Menu. E.g. `sudo efibootmgr -b 1 -B`

`-b`: modify boot number `-B`: delete boot number

There after, all I did was to switch *Windows Boot Manager* back up to the top of the Boot Menu > go back to Windows 10 > *Create and format hard disk partitions* and extended my Windows `C:\` Drive partition to merge with the *free space* where it came from my deleted Ubuntu drive.

---

Reference (with images): [How to remove Ubuntu from Dual Boot](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2016/06/how-to-remove-ubuntu-from-dual-boot.html)

Comment: `C:\Users\Rahul kumar>x:
Access is denied.`

Comment: It is showing when i type `x:`

Answer (score 14):

Open the Command Prompt (Admin) ( shown in the options image above ).
Follow these commands->
Note the line after ‘#’ is just to explain the command

```
> diskpart  
> list disk       # select the primary disk
> select disk 0   # disk 0 is 
> list partition   # a list of partition is opened

Note-> Check which is the system partition (example partition 1 is system partition)

> select partition 1  #select the system partition
> assign letter=x     #disk is now mounted in your explorer verify with (windows+E)
>exit    #exit from diskpart
>x:      # this would select this newly mounted disk x:
> dir  # displays content
> cd efi
>dir   #displays content

Note-> You can now see the OS check your Linux OS

>rd ubuntu /S    #if Linux os is Ubuntu
>y               #to confirm delete
```

You may check out my article 
[UNINSTALL UBUNTU COMPLETELY](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/uninstall-linux-completely-from-a-pc-with-windows/)

Comment: Sorry just saw you solved the problem but this answer would help other so wrote it.

Comment: This was extremely helpful since I didn't have my Ubuntu flash drive on hand.