# Remove Windows 10 from 18.04 desktop boot menu

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.04

I replaced a copy of Windows 10 with Ubuntu 18.04 desktop successfully. The only problem that remains is that the Windows 10 boot selection entry still appears. I know that disabling the OS probe will work around the problem but I would prefer to get rid of whatever is causing OS probe to think that Windows 10 is still there.

EDIT: I am going the other way than what was suggested in the comment. I overwrote the Windows partition with an ext4 bootable partition.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove "Ubuntu" from Boot Menu after deleting Ubuntu partition in Windows 10 (Dual Boot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921046/how-to-remove-ubuntu-from-boot-menu-after-deleting-ubuntu-partition-in-windows)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove Windows from grub menu and boot straight to ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/166776/how-to-remove-windows-from-grub-menu-and-boot-straight-to-ubuntu)

Comment: If UEFI probably this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi, you have to remove the /EFI/Microsoft folder in ESP and Windows boot entry in UEFI with efibootmgr.

Answer (score 0):

First list your boot entries:

```
$ efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000,0003,0007
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0003  Onboard NIC (IPV4)
Boot0007  Onboard NIC (IPV6)
```

In my case it is Windows 10 is `Boot0000`.

Using these instructions: [How to delete boot managers from a UEFI boot menu](http://linuxbsdos.com/2014/06/02/how-to-delete-boot-managers-from-a-uefi-boot-menu/), I would type:

```
efibootmgr -b 0000 -B
```

Please read the linked article very carefully and make sure you fully understand the process. If not ask below or post a new question if your rep doesn't allow posting comments.