# Removing Ubuntu entry from OS Boot Manager

Tags: dual-boot, bios

I deleted Ubuntu a couple months ago but it's entry is still listed in Windows OS Boot Manager in BIOS. Refer to the picture attached. Any way to get rid of it?

[Ubuntu entry in OS Boot Manager in Windows BIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcWEz.jpg)

I have tried this method: https://askubuntu.com/a/923231/1560697, but it didn't work.

Comment: I guess, you can try to remove this entry by using the "Windows Boot Manager".

Comment: If you did it as explained in the answer from a live session it must have worked. If it didin't then you did something wrong. There are many other methods, from Windows with Windows software, from UEFI settings directly, etc. And, of course, it's something that you can leave exactly as it is without any consequences whatsoever.

Comment: Of note: Your terminology is incorrect, everywhere. (1) You have UEFI, not BIOS (UEFI replaced the old BIOS some 10 years ago) (2) In any case there isn't and never was any "Windows BIOS" (or "Windows UEFI"), the motherboard's firmware is OS independent and OS agnostic and it runs *before* any OS (3) Ubuntu is still listed, as expected, in the UEFI Boot menu which is NOT and could NOT be the "Windows OS Boot Manager" (4) In multi-boot configurations in UEFI mode all bootloaders co-exist in the EFI System Partition

Comment: @FedKad Thanks for telling me where to look at, Windows Boot Manager was where I can solve this problem.

Following this "guide" solved the issue: [link](https://gist.github.com/henrytriplette/bc5ec3742896e36503b9a99d0940a4e4#file-windows-10-grub-remove-md)