# Is it save to remove ubuntu folder from EFI/ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I already remove ubuntu partition in my disk. Now ubuntu still showing in boot menu BIOS windows 10.

Last time I try tutorial from this site but I cannot boot my windows 10, and I don't know why, after I put usb bootable that contain ubuntu and open ubuntu live, my windows can boot again.

So I just wanna make sure that what I will do is save.

I check system partition and see folder **boot, Microsoft and ubuntu**.

Last modified in ubuntu folder is 02/20/2022, that the time when I install ubuntu dual boot

And **Boot** folder created in the same time, 02/20/2022

So i'm afraid if I remove **EFI/ubuntu** folder will effect for my **EFI/boot** folder

So the question is, can I delete EFI/ubuntu folder?

If I do that, is ubuntu option will dissapear from my boot menu in BIOS?

What will happend to EFI/Boot folder if I delete EFI/ubuntu folder?

And, is this will effect to my windows 10?

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Does your computer have *only* Windows 10 installed now?

Comment: @matigo yes, I already delete my ubuntu partition and set windows 10 to first entry on boot menu

Comment: As this is a Windows question, it's technically off-topic for AskUbuntu. That said, [this SuperUser answer](https://superuser.com/a/1169899/1655497) will show you how to restore the EFI to be Windows-only 

Comment: @matigo is this tutorial will effect to my windows 10? https://askubuntu.com/a/960232/1567675