# Ubuntu is not deleted completely

Tags: dual-boot

i deleted the partition of Linux in windows 10 and then change the boot sequence to windows boot loader but now what happens is that neither the partition is adding to another partition nor when I try to install Ubuntu 17.04 the pc do not boot from usb drive instead shows a option boot from Ubuntu 14.04 (previous one that I deleted).

Comment: Do you know where Grub (the boot loader) was installed? May be grub was installed on `/dev/sda` and although the Ubuntu partition was deleted, Grub is still there, trying to boot Ubuntu.

Comment: no it was /dev/sda4

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some bits of GRUB are left intact. Recipes for various situations (including UEFI systems) are discussed in answers to [Uninstall Grub and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/q/429610/735629).

Comment: I appreciate it but i am not able to boot neither via usb nor cd drive. There is only two options coming i.e. ubuntu and windows bootloader

Comment: i tried the command prompt option but it didn't worked

Comment: Then more details is needed. What was the initial situation? What have you done and using what tools? What kind of system you have UEFI?