# How to remove grub at startup

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, bootloader

I had Windows 7 on my machine and then I have installed Ubuntu as dual boot. This works well. But for installing Ubuntu I had somehow to install a grub tool.

So everytime I restart my PC, the grub command window appears and I have to enter *exit* to leave it. Afterwards the grub boot loader appears which is fine.

How can I remove this initial grub thing?

Edit: I'm not talking about the grub bootloader. The problem is the stuff appearing before the bootloader appears. Below is a screenshot. I have to enter 1-2x *exit* to leave it.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uninstall Grub and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader)

Comment: @derHugo It is not a duplicate because I'm not talking about the bootloader. See my edit.

Comment: grub **is** the bootloader. Did you have a look on provided answers in my link?

Comment: I think the problem the OP is having is that the grub command prompt appears on each boot, instead of the grub menu (the OS list).  The OP wants to see the list of OS options (Windows, Ubuntu, etc) so he can make a selection.

Comment: @PJSingh Correct. The grub menu appears but first the grub command prompt appears. When I exit the grub command prompt, the grub menu appears. I want to get rid of the grub command prompt but NOT of the grub menu.

Comment: Could you please run [Boot-Info](//help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) and [edit] your question to include a link to its resulting info log? Thanks.