# I deleted my Ubuntu 17.10 partition, and now I can't boot into anything

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, grubrescue

I deleted my Ubuntu partition, thinking that would delete Ubuntu off of my PC, but now I can't do anything on it.
Now, whenever I turn on my PC, I go straight into a command line which says:

`error: no such partition.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>`

Comment: Ubuntu may be gone, but stage 1 of GNU GRUB remains, and now points to a deleted partition so can't run later stages of GRUB which ask which OS you want to boot. To fix, you must use whatever else is one your system (boot it's live system) and enter the commands it uses for it to take over your systems MBR (master boot record). Whatever OS remains will dictate what you need to do, but you've not told us that...  (if windoze, use system recovery disk (commands vary by version), if another GNU/Linux use it's live media to ...)

Comment: I'm on Windows, but I'm not sure how to access my recovery disk.

Comment: Possible duplicate of {Uninstall Grub and use Windows bootloader;https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader}  *the commands for restoration vary on version of windoze as already stated; you didn't provide version so adjust accordingly..*

Comment: I can't access my computer at all though, besides going into the BIOS.

Comment: this may help https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1014708  it does require your recovery-disk (*provided when new for many, some provided a card that you mailed away for it [with p&h cost]), some allowed you to download & write your own or send away, later systems have recovery on installed hdd/sdd)  Refer to "**How to restore the Windows Vista or 7 bootloader**" section.  It also includes a link to download replacement dvd if you can't find yours.

Comment: Could I maybe reinstall Ubuntu instead?

Comment: Yes that would work too, but its a roundabout way of allowing yourself to boot.  I'd just download the correct windows recovery media, boot it & put a new MBR on your system that will boot your OS; a total of 512 bytes of data only needs to be written to your system.  I've provided two links for this; pick the correct one for your version of windoze.