# How to recreate removed Ubuntu entry from EFI partition?

Tags: uefi, 17.10, lenovo

On my Lenovo Y50-70 laptop i had both Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.10. 
I've tried to remove. Ubuntu I've followed those instructions: https://askubuntu.com/a/869888/45439 to remove ubuntu from EFI just to realize that I'm affected by this kernel bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147

Currently I'm only able to boot into windows. Is there a way to recreate EFI entry for Ubuntu from Windows? I assume this would allow me to fix the kernel bug by updating the kernel.

Comment: Hi, so you removed only the folder "ubuntu" from your EFI folder and your Linux system partition is still available? Are you able to boot with USB?

Comment: Yes exactly, I've removed it from EFI and Ubuntu is intact. I cannot boot from USB due to the kernel bug I've mentioned.

Comment: OK.. can you again assign letter Z: and try to access this EFI folder with in Windows? I tried some times to see the contents in it but messed with permissions. If you can access this EFI folder.. I suggest you to take the copy of Ubuntu folder from another 17.10 system and paste it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@PRATAP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1054330/how-to-recreate-removed-ubuntu-entry-from-efi-partition?noredirect=1#comment1724055_1054330) answer I was able to recover grub and boot into Ubuntu. Thanks!

Steps to fix:

1. I've installed Ubuntu 17.10 on Virtual box.
2. Copy `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu` to `Z:\EFI\ubuntu`
3. Thanks to [How to Rescue a Non-booting GRUB 2 on Linux](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-rescue-non-booting-grub-2-linux) article I was able to boot Ubuntu. Basicly in my case:

   ```
   grub> set root=(hd0,1)
   grub> linux /vmlinuz root=/dev/sda1
   grub> initrd /initrd.img
   grub> boot
   ```
4. After booting into Ubuntu I've fixed grub config `sudo update-grub`
5. Following the instructions from the [description of the bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147) I've installed Kernel linux-image-4.15.0-041500rc6-generic_4.15.0-041500rc6.201712312330+20170103+1_amd64
6. After 2 reboots I was able to change BIOS settings once again

Comment: You did a miracle.