# Fix Grub: No such device found

Tags: grubrescue

I Dual booted Windows 7 and Ubuntu on my pc, using two different drives. I deleted and reformatted the ubuntu partition. Now when I start my computer, it pulls up Grub saying there is no such device. I can't reinstall anything due to grub saying there is no such device everytime I boot from usb. My computer is unusable because of that.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Grub is found in the /boot/grub/ directory on your Ubuntu system.  In there are stages 1.5-2 that pull up your dual-boot & grub menu.  Stage 1 is located in the MBR; and when you deleted the Ubuntu partition you deleted the menu & stages 1.5 & up, and should have told whatever you used to delete the partition (I'm guessing windows 7) to replace grub's MBR with the windows mbr (`bootrec /fixmbr` etc). You no longer have Ubuntu, no longer have grub pointer to a deleted-partition. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uninstall Grub and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader)

Comment: With two drives you should have Windows boot loader on Windows drive and grub boot loader on Ubuntu drive. Are both systems installed in BIOS boot mode or both installed in UEFI boot mode? Do not run auto fix as that installs grub to both drives which you do not want. Only use advanced mode, but best to wait for someone to review report. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please attach link to the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

See if you can boot into Windows 7 normally.

If you can, navigate to your web browser and install EasyBCD.

Get your install image ISO file ready. You’ll need it to continue.

#### Step 1: Getting the ISO onto the Metro Bootloader

Open EasyBCD. Firstly, enable the “Metro” bootloader. Next, navigate to the “Add an Entry” tab, and find the tab named “ISO” inside of the 2nd tab list (inside the add tab). Put in the ISO, type in a name, and click the “Add Entry” button.

#### Step 2: Check the Entry List

Now, look at the entries (in the first main tab) and make sure your entry is inside the list. If so, restart your computer and try booting into Windows 7. Else, repeat the first step.

#### Step 3: Booting into the ISO

When you see a list of options, find the one that you added in EasyBCD. Select it. It should start the ISO.