# Uninstall Ubuntu Dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uninstall

After installing Windows 10 on a partition, I want to remove Ubuntu 18.04 completely and use the entire hdd for Windows.  Can I delete the partition with Windows still working? I’m not sure if grub will affect the boot.

Comment: Depends on whether UEFI or BIOS. Duplicate if UEFI: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi
http://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader/497720?noredirect=1#comment1369050_497720

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow the below steps properly:

**STEP - I: Deleting Ubuntu Partitions**

- Boot into `Windows` OS
- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> keys together and type `diskmgmt.msc` to enter into your disk management utility
- You can easily recognize the Ubuntu partition by their size. Another hint to recognize the partitions is to look at the partitions which don’t have a file system and drive number. Windows partition is labeled with a drive number such as C, D, E etc and are usually in NTFS or FAT file system
- Manually select all your Ubuntu partitions one by one and right click on each and select the option - **Delete Volume**
- All the deleted space will show as Unallocated on your Windows partition table. Now, either extend any of your existing partitions or simply create a new partition (using the entire Unallocated space you got)

**STEP II: Fixing the Boot loader**

- Use your Windows OS disk and restart your computer. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> at the boot time to go into BIOS/UEFI and choose to boot from removable disk
- Select 'Repair your computer' option
- Go for the 'Troubleshoot' option here and then select 'Advanced options'
- Look for the 'command prompt' option and select it
- Once you enter into the command-line interface, type the following command:
  `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`
- Once it’s done, restart your computer and this time boot normally from the hard disk. You should be able to boot into Windows.

In case you encounter **Grub rescue error**, try the steps below:

- If the command `bootrec.exe /fixmbr` did not work, try the 'Automatic Repair' option in advanced troubleshoot option
- It will find the issue and take some time to repair it

Once done, reboot your system and you should be able to boot into Windows OS directly (with no GRUB options).

Comment: Fix Boot loader first and confirm it directly boots Windows before deleting any partitions. The grub boot loader has parts of it in the Ubuntu folder and you may not be able to boot if you delete partitions and then reboot before installing Windows boot loader.

Comment: for step one i see that the ubuntu partition if left to my windows drive and is not allowing me to extend backwards

Answer (score -1):

If you dont have your windows boot disk or pendrive you can download the exact same version of windows (for eg. If you are using win8.1 there are different version like single language and win8.1core etc. ) select it and download that (preferably from microsoft’s own website”It’s free”) and take any pendrive and make it bootable using the downloaded iso file image.Then use it as mentioned above!!Worked for me!! (I didnt have my windows installation disk!!) Hope it helps!!

Answer (score -1):

Run cmd as administrator
Diskpart
List disk
Sel disk 0 (if boot partition on the disk 0. On my system only one disk so disk 0)
List vol
Sel vol 2(if the EFI boot partition on volume 2 which can be guessed boot partition is a FAT 32. On my system, it is volume 2)
Assign letter=Z: (safest side)
Exit
Z:
Dir
Cd EFI
Rmdir /S Ubuntu grub