# After uninstaling ubuntu dual-boot, Windows 8.1 still boot with GRUB even after bootrec fixmbr

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

So I uninstalled Ubuntu 16.04 following this [step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123089/uninstall-ubuntu-dual-boot), I delete the partition on which Ubuntu resides from disk management tools.

I also boot Windows from USB, got into cmd and did `bootrec.exe /fixmbr` succesfully

Right now, my PC still boot GNU GRUB
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5OLM.jpg)
But when I do `exit` it could boot normally to Windows

My question is:

1. Why GRUB is still booted even after bootrec.exe \fixmbr what did I miss?
2. I want to reinstall Ubuntu on new allocated volume, will this current condition affect the installation?

I'll be glad to provide you with any necessary details

*Note:  Windows have issues regarding creating new file, opening new file and copying file after `bootrec.exe \fixmbr`, but this was sovled with windows auto disk repair*

Comment: Your `bootrec` command you've written differently (twice with errors) so it may not have worked depending on how you actually typed it.  However that's a windows issue, and is off-topic here as this is a Ubuntu (and official flavor) support site - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic   I would expect a Ubuntu install to work, but some UEFI/BIOS setups can be problematic and you haven't specified your device/setup.

Comment: so it might not run successfully although, the console said successfully, okay I'll remove this post, thankss man!

Comment: On all nearby hp, dell & lenovo boxes (9) that came with windows installed, I'd expect a Ubuntu install to work perfectly; but I have a single sony crap thingy with a really limited/restrictive bios/uefi setup that came with win8 & it was a pain until I removed its pre-installed windows. Going by my nearby machines; 10% of boxes only **may** have issues with re-install of Ubuntu.

Comment: If UEFI: https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi