# How can I remove options from bios boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, lenovo, bios

I was using openSUSE and Manjaro before I start using Ubuntu (kubuntu). Now there's boot options such as windows boot manager, Manjaro, debian, etc. How can I delete those options from my Lenovo laptop bios boot menu?

Comment: If UEFI boot menu you use efibootmgr with -b parmeter, details in `man efibootmgr`. Duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader/497720#497720

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your Ubuntu terminal using the key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and follow the below procedure:

- Paste the following command in terminal `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`. It will open a file named `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file
- Add `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=true` at the bottom of this file
- It will prevent `Windows` being added to your grub menu
- Now to write the change, run the command: `sudo update-grub`
- You can then run `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg` to check that your `Windows` OS entry has disappeared.
- Restart your device to check the same

Comment: Dude I'm using Ubuntu not Windows.

Comment: @A.Hayati - Answer updated. Check and mark it as correct if it works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I use "Grub Customizer" which is an easy to use GUI tool to remove or change your grub menu.

There's a whole tutorial on how to download and how to use it [here](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-change-boot-order-set-default-boot-os-in-ubuntu-14-10-15-04-linux-mint-or-other-derivatives) - You really don't need to read it though.

Basically you just install it and choose which options you want from the GUI (it's very simple)

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Comment: It's seems to be editor for grub. It only shows my Ubuntu option not other options I used before (like windows boot manager or manjaro)

Comment: Yeah that's pretty much what it is, but it should show your others boot options as well. Mine shows my Windows boot. Are you running a dual boot setup?

Comment: No. I only have Ubuntu (kubuntu).

Comment: And you are saying that there are options when you start your pc, which you have to select between to start the OS?

Comment: Yes. there's other options like windows boot manager. They can't be selected (if you select, computer restarts) but they're there.