# Reconfiguring dual boot (Ubuntu and Windows) - Grub2

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, uefi

I have new Acer Nitro 5 which has both SSD and HDD disks in it, also it came with  Windows 10 pre-installed in SSD.

I have migrated the Windows OS to HDD, and installed Ubuntu 18 in SSD.

But while doing that I have messed up EFI partitions.

Now I one-one EFI partitions on both SSD and HDD each, and on boot menu (in BIOS settings), I have four options:

- ubuntu boot-loader (SSD)
- ubuntu boot-loader (HDD)
- Windows (SSD)
- Windows (HDD)

And Windows boot option from grub boot-loader does not work, for which I have to select Windows (HDD) option from BIOS settings.

How do I reconfigure my grub2 to correct this?

Comment: Run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: If you have entries in both ESP, grub will find both sets on an update. If some are not valid, backup ESP and delete folders you do not want. You also may have entries in UEFI boot menu that you can delete with efibootmgr. See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader/497720#497720