# Can't remove Ubuntu from boot priority order

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bios

It seems that I can't completely remove Ubuntu from BIOS/Firmware settings of my PC; I also use Windows 10, by the way.

I already removed the partitions where I had Ubuntu, and extended my Windows partition. I also applied the command `bootrec /fixmbr` using my recovery USB drive, and tried to remove the 'Ubuntu` directory from my system volume using the Windows command line, but neither of those worked.

For removing my Ubuntu directory with the command line, I [followed these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/429610/uninstall-grub-and-use-windows-bootloader). My issue is that I'm still having Ubuntu and Linux-Firmware-Updater listed in the Boot Priority Order of my BIOS. I'm attaching a picture showing my Boot Priority Order in my BIOS. [image: Bios' Boot priority order]

Do you know how I can remove them? Thank you so much.

Thanks a lot for replying. 
These are the results of the command LENOVO 20MDCTO1WW  LAPTOP-P8VUAKRF  x64-based PC

Comment: check [this](https://superuser.com/a/931016/1001901)

Comment: You can also use efibootmgr, but may need to also remove /EFI/ubuntu folder from ESP - efi system partition. Uninstall Ubuntu from menu, Really UEFI boot menu 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi

Comment: Please run `wmic computersystem get model,name,manufacturer,systemtype` and paste the result into your question after clicking [edit]. Also please put two space characters after each end of line before you press Enter so what you post formats well onscreen.  Please do not click on Add Comment as new comments can shove old comments off screen; your information about your PC and installation should all go in the Question so we can all see your findings.