# Why is /dev/sda1 not recognized as a windows bootable by boot-repair?

Tags: dual-boot

In an older configuration I had a sata SSD drive with windows and linux working both with grub (/dev/sda)

Later I added a faster ssd card (/dev/nvme0) and installed a more recent version of Ubuntu on it and made that faster ssd card the first boot.

For a while I could still dual boot but to get to Windows I always had to change in the BIOS the first boot to that /dev/sda drive (annoying) because the grub installed on /dev/nvme0 never could make my windows run, only the older grub installed on /dev/sda could run it.

Today I wanted to recuperate the unused partitions (my older linux still on the /dev/sda) so I changed its type, zeroed its content and since then I never could boot in Windows.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wc6C7CQghZ/

I used boot-repair but it does not consider /dev/sda1 as a bootable windows partition but it should... what's going on?

Comment: Boot-Repair did not solve this problem. I suggest that you try some of the answers to [Uninstall Grub and use Windows bootloader](https://askubuntu.com/q/429610), the ones that don't require Windows OS to be bootable. After that if Windows is able to boot you can repair grub if necessary with Boot-Repair, so that Ubuntu boots too.

Comment: Windows install looks like a typical BIOS type install, not UEFI type. Windows only boots from UEFI with gpt and only with BIOS from MBR(msdos). And grub only boots other installs in same boot mode and only a working Windows. And you are showing dos(MBR) on your NVMe drive but also an ESP and UEFI shows Ubuntu? Best not to mix UEFI(gpt) and BIOS(MBR) and definitely not UEFI & BIOS on same drive. Either convert Ubuntu back to 35 year old BIOS boot or reinstall Windows in UEFI boot mode to gpt drive, and Ubuntu to UEFI/gpt on NVMe drive.

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI . One will have the Answer. Read the others to understand that one.